# How to insert a counter inside math mode?

Tags: math-mode, counters

I am looking for a way to insert a counter in the math mode $ .* $.
In particular, I am writing a document in LaTex and I want to check the grammar within the document with a language tool. First, I removed all the math by following the answer to the following question: [remove everything in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89622/remove-everything-that-is-in-math-mode).
However, by removing all the math, the language tool reports errors because of the empty string between words. Therefore, I would like to insert a counter in order to have something between words. I tried the following

```
\newcounter{equat}
\setcounter{equat}{1}
\newcommand{\newEQ}{\refstepcounter{equat}\Alph{equat}}
\def$#1${\newEQ}
```

but apparently, I cannot use `\stepcounter`, `\refstepcounter` or `\addtocounter` in `\def$#1${.*}`.
Does anyone know how I can increase the above counter?
I thought about inserting the `\refstepcounter` before (or after) the math mode, but I cannot find how to do it.

I thank everyone in advance!

---

**Working example**

I have this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\def\[#1\]{}
\def\(#1\){}
\catcode`\$=13
\def$$#1$${}
\def$#1${}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{subequations}{\comment}{\endcomment}
\renewenvironment{equation}{\comment}{\endcomment}
\renewenvironment{alignat}{\comment}{\endcomment}
\renewenvironment{align}{\comment}{\endcomment}
\renewenvironment{equation*}{\comment}{\endcomment}
\renewenvironment{alignat*}{\comment}{\endcomment}
\renewenvironment{align*}{\comment}{\endcomment}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    This is an example with $ E = m c^2 $ and 
    \begin{equation*}
        \cos^2(\alpha) + \sin^2(\alpha) = 1.
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

If I compile the above code, I get:

```
This is an example with and
```

However, I want something like the following

```
This is an example A with B.
```

where **A** and **B** are the alphabetic conversion of a counter.

If I put the command `\newEQ` inside the redefinition of the above environment, the I solve this problem only for the environments:

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{subequations}{\newEQ\comment}{\endcomment\ }
\renewenvironment{equation}{\newEQ\comment}{\endcomment\ }
\renewenvironment{alignat}{\newEQ\comment}{\endcomment\ }
\renewenvironment{align}{\newEQ\comment}{\endcomment\ }
\renewenvironment{equation*}{\newEQ\comment}{\endcomment\ }
\renewenvironment{alignat*}{\newEQ\comment}{\endcomment\ }
\renewenvironment{align*}{\newEQ\comment}{\endcomment\ }
\makeatother
```

Indeed, I got the following result

```
This is an example with A
```

Comment: Please write a minimal working example. See [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) for more details what it means.

Comment: You can't use `\def$#1$` in the first place, no matter what you're doing. If you want numbered equations use the `equation` environment.

Comment: "no matter what you're doing" might factually be incorrect, this is possible with a bit of extra code, but I won't ever advise a beginner to do this, this is bound to bring lots of errors.

Comment: @Skillmon I do not want to number the equation. By the way, the working example is the same as in the question I linked (where there is also the line `catcode'$=\active` before `\def$#1$`. I want to substitute the formulas into the math mode with a counter in order to have a clean PDF to analyze with a language tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works in the minimal example. Please note that `\def$#1${}` does overwrite the prior `\def$$#1$${}`, instead the following defines only `$` and uses LaTeX's `\@ifnextchar` to see if the following char is another `$`, based on that it either gobbles until the next `$` or `$$`.

Also I used the `alphalph` package so that your document can contain more than 26 equations.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{alphalph}

\newcounter{myequat}
\renewcommand*\themyequat{\AlphAlph{\value{myequat}}}
\newcommand*\newEQ{}
\protected\def\newEQ{\refstepcounter{myequat}\themyequat}

\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\protected\def\[#1\]{\newEQ}
\protected\def\(#1\){\newEQ}
\makeatletter
\catcode`\$=13
\protected\def${\newEQ\@ifnextchar$\@gobbledisplay\@gobbleinline}
\def\@gobbledisplay$#1$${}
\def\@gobbleinline#1${}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{subequations}{\newEQ\comment}{\endcomment}
\renewenvironment{equation}{\newEQ\comment}{\endcomment}
\renewenvironment{alignat}{\newEQ\comment}{\endcomment}
\renewenvironment{align}{\newEQ\comment}{\endcomment}
\renewenvironment{equation*}{\newEQ\comment}{\endcomment}
\renewenvironment{alignat*}{\newEQ\comment}{\endcomment}
\renewenvironment{align*}{\newEQ\comment}{\endcomment}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    This is an example with $ E = m c^2 $ and 
    \begin{equation*}
        \cos^2(\alpha) + \sin^2(\alpha) = 1.
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works but there is still a problem. When formulas are into the title of a section, it is not possible to compile as I got this message `Missing \endcsname inserted.`. Is it possible to solve this latter problem?

Comment: @G.F how should they get numbered in the ToC? Independent from their occurences later in the document? If so, put `\protect` before each `$` in section titles, or change the line defining it to `\protected\def${\@ifnextchar$\@gobbledisplay\@gobbleinline}`.

Comment: same for `\(` and `\[`, add a `\protected` in front of `\def`.

Comment: thank you so much!