# Convert all formulas to image hevea

Tags: graphics, hevea

I'm using [Hevea](http://hevea.inria.fr/) to translate TeX to HTML. I want to convert all the formulas enclosed by `$ ... $` to images. But I'm trying to avoid the using of:

```
\begin{toimage} 
  $ ... $ 
\end{toimage} \imageflush
```

There is some way to redefine the dollar sign, (perhaps using a `\hevea` macro) so as append all the `toimage` environments in a transparent way?
I mean just using the dollar sign. Nothing else.

I've tried the approach described in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59980/can-i-redefine-the-dollar) but the macro cannot be parsed by hevea.

Example added:

I just want to translate everything like (this is an example, I want every formula written in math mode to be modified).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}        
    $ \textbf{\overrightarrow{x}} = ( \frac{3}{2} x,y,z) $
\end{document}
```

to

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
    %\begin{toimage} 
    $ \textbf{\overrightarrow{x}} = ( \frac{3}{2} x,y,z) $
    %\end{toimage} \imageflush
\end{document}
```

Because is the way I know to make hevea translates something written in math mode to an image. Hevea parse that commets %\begin{toimage}, etc and generate the images.
I don't know is there a options of hevea to make that. But i couldn't find it so i try this approach, i.e. modifying the dollar sign.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a clue how hevea works, what it does and how to use it, *but* the following MWE does get compiled by pdfLaTeX.

It would be easier to do, if you use the LaTeX macros `\(` and `\)` for inline math and `\[` and `\]` for display math.

### Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hevea}
\catcode`$=\active
\makeatletter
\begingroup
    \catcode`\"=3
    \protected\gdef${\@ifnextchar$\@doubledollar\@singledollar}
    \gdef\@doubledollar$#1$${\begin{toimage}""#1""\end{toimage}}%        display math
    \gdef\@singledollar#1${\begin{toimage}"#1"\end{toimage}\imageflush}% inline math
\endgroup
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    $ \vec{x} = \left( \frac{3}{2} x,y,z\right) $
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That code fails with hevea because it could not understand the \active command.
I think you are right, it going to be easier rewriting the `\(` and `\)`. Hevea almost understand the translation but fails too, (less catastrophically although, the translation finishes throwing some warnings).

I used this macro 
       
    `\let\oldO\(
    \let\oldC\)
    \renewcommand{\(}{ %\begin{toimage} 
                  \oldO }
    \renewcommand{\)}{ \oldC      %
    \end{toimage}}`

I'm going to write in their mailing list, to see if they can help me.

Comment: @LucianoLorenti Does your solution work? Post it as an answer than. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you reputation. If it does not work edit your approach in your question. (I will delete my answer soon.)