# How to override TeX dollars?

Tags: math-mode, catcodes

I've read about `\renewenvironment` and `\let` commands but they are intended 
to work with classic commands TeX commands that start with a slash.

And I cannot find any example of overriding `$` and `$$` any how.

Is it possible?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Can you please add more details about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59980/can-i-redefine-the-dollar?rq=1 ?

Answer (score 6):

You need to change the category code (catcode) of `$` to something other than math shift.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\catcode`$=12
This costs many $$.
\end{document}
```

You can have all sorts of fun changing catcodes; here the catcode of `u` is changed to math shift.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\catcode`u=3
an equation. another equation
\end{document}
```

See chapter 2 of the free book [TeX by Topic](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texbytopic) for more details. Be warned, though -
changing catcodes is a risky business that is likely to break just about everything.

Comment: Out of curiosity (and for completeness): what is the catcode for math shift? If I'd like to use another character as math shift, how would I do it?

Comment: It is 3. There is a list in [TeX by Topic](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/texbytopic).

Comment: There’s also one in our [catcodes tag wiki](http://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/catcodes/info).

Comment: @IanThompson I'd assign catcode 12 and not 11 to `$`

Comment: @egreg --- indeed; fixed.