# Search for LaTeX in PDF

Tags: pdf, viewers

Is it possible to search for LaTeX characters like `\alpha` in a PDF file? Perhaps there's some PDF reader that can do that?

Comment: Just search for `α`.  If you want to make equations copyable and searchable in PDF see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119718/31416

Comment: @giordano That is a great feature! Are you sure those `ActualText`s are searchable as well? (too lazy to test right now)

Comment: @MHaaZ yes, I tried before posting `;-)`

Answer (score 5):

It's not quite as comfortable as it could be, but here's how I do it:

- Open the Character Map on your system
- Copy the symbol you want to search for in the PDF
- Do a normal text search (Ctrl+F on most readers) and paste the special symbol

Of course this only works with single symbols and not if you want to search for bigger parts of formulas (for example something like `\frac{\alpha}{8 \times d_{k}^{3.17}}`. Still, better than nothing...

For me, this works with the PDF Viewer `evince` to find the small character "α" (`\alpha`). It works for pretty much every Unicode character you want to look for.