# Copy and paste unicode math

Tags: luatex, unicode, unicode-math, copy-paste

Consider the following example compiled with `luatex`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\begin{document}
$A_1$
\end{document}
```

Since `Latin Modern Math` is a unicode math font, I though I could copy and paste from the resulting `.pdf` file the two corresponding unicode characters:

```
u+1d434 (mathematical italic capital a)
u+2081 (subscript one)
```

I'd like to get: ₁

But it does not work with `evince` as my viewer and `emacs` as my editor. `emacs` correctly displays ₁ when copy pasted from a [web](http://xahlee.info/math/math_unicode_greek.html) [page](http://xahlee.info/comp/unicode_math_operators.html)

Note that `u+2081 (subscript one)` does not appear in `unimath-symbols.pdf`.

So is | would | will it be possible to copy and paste unicode math from a `luatex`-generated `.pdf` ? If the answer is yes, how complex can the mathematical expression be?

Comment: In TeX `$A_1$` does not involve the `subscript one` character.  TeX works with boxes and thus places a `1` from the scriptsize font in a box and lowers it below the baseline.

Comment: Subscripts are implemented by switching to a smaller font, not by switching the symbol -- after all you could want all sorts of characters in the subscripts. Beside this: Simple copy & paste can't reliable reproduce math expressions. See e.g. `$A_{1^2}$` versus `$A_1^2$`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ok so there is no invisible information stored within the `.pdf` file for OpenType math fonts. I'll stick with [Heiko's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119718/8425).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle you could do something like this, based on [Heiko's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119718/8425):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2081}{\ensuremath{_{\BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=2081}1\EndAccSupp{}}}}%
\begin{document}
$A₁$
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work because some component in the chain (accsupp, LaTeX, or the PDF reader) thinks itself smart and turns the subscript `₁` into a regular `1`. This happens both with Evince and Okular on my machine.

**EDIT:** The PDF reader sems to be at fault. When I search for `A1` in Evince, the search bar result correctly shows `A₁`, but copying the text yields `A 1`.