# How to compile a document that you can search the pdf for latex math formulas?

Tags: math-mode, pdf, copy-paste

Is it possible to compile a latex-document in such a way, that you can search for math formulas in the resulting pdf file by searching for the corresponding latex code? For example open the resulting document in evince and search for `\int_3^5 f` and you will find all occurrences the typeset math formula where the source contained `\int_3^5 f`.

The normal pdf search function should be unaffected.

I think in principle this should be possible since you could parse the math information at compile time and add them appropriately to the pdf ocr layer. However is there already a package or option which implements this?

Comment: As a simple workaround: You could print the code invisible (white color on white background using `verbatim`) and use negative spaces to align stuff right.

Comment: I think the accsup package is what you're looking for: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119713/making-equations-copyable-in-pdf