# Search subscript in pdf

Tags: viewers

I'd like to know if it's possible to search subscript terms in a pdf, by using keywords like `F_k`, when you can't have access to sources (so basically I can't use [this idea](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119713/making-equations-copyable-in-pdf/119718#119718)).

Thank you!