# Make automatically equation copyable in pdf

Tags: equations, pdf, copy-paste, accessibility

I would like to write a .pdf where **all** rendered equations can be copied and pasted correctly as TeX code. Someone had posted a similar question : 
[https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119713/making-equations-copyable-in-pdf#*=*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119713/making-equations-copyable-in-pdf#_=_)

Here is a response he gets for copy and paste **one** equation :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accsupp}

\newcommand*{\copyable}[1]{%
\BeginAccSupp{%
ActualText=\detokenize{#1},%
method=escape,
}%
#1%
\EndAccSupp{}%
}

\begin{document}
\[
 \copyable{\int x\sin ax\;\mathrm{d}x = \frac{\sin ax}{a^2}-\frac{x\cos ax}{a}+C}
\]
\end{document}
```

I would like to apply this command to **all** mathmode script. A sort of

```
\AtEveryMath{\copyable}
```

Is it possible ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Also here (in macro form): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233390/in-which-way-have-fake-spaces-made-it-to-actual-use

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thank you for posting a related topic ! In the "revised solution", \copyable is also not automatic.

Comment: That is correct, that it is **not** automatic, though a macro form is an improvement.

Comment: I have posted an answer that (partially) works to the linked question, so I close this one as duplicate. Anyone who wants to post another answer to this question can likewise do that at the linked question, for better visibility.