# Big LaTeX delimiters have a weird encoding in the pdf. How can I avoid this?

Tags: pdf, unicode, copy-paste, accessibility

I noticed recently that changing the size of parentheses in LaTeX results in a different encoding of the text in the pdf (as determined using the copy/paste functionality in my pdf viewer). For instance, in the command

```
$\sin(x) + \sin\bigl(x\bigr)$
```

the first term is encoded as `s i n ( x )` whereas the second term is encoded as
`s i n <CR> <LF> <U+FFFD> <CR> <LF> x <CR> <LF> <U+FFFD>`. (Here `<CR>` is [carriage return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return), `<LF>` is [line feed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Unicode), and `<U+FFFD>` is the unicode symbol for an [unknown, unrecognised, or unrepresentable character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block))).

This behavior is undesirable because it makes it impossible to find all instance of "sin(x)" by searching the file. As a mathematician who exclusively reads papers and books on the computer, I find it very important that pdf documents be easily searchable. This is also critical from an accessibility perspective.

**Question**: Is there any easy way to improve the encoding of the pdf file so that (for instance) the two terms above are encoded in the same way?

This site has [a related problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119713/making-equations-copyable-in-pdf) that was solved using the `accsupp` package, but in my case that method results in the text string `\sin (x) + \sin \big (x\big )`, which is not so desirable either and is a hassle to make work in the LaTeX file. [Random question: do some visually impaired users prefer that the size of delimiters be recorded, as this output suggests?]

Comment: It depends on the font and on engine  what happens here so you shouldn't show only snippets but a complete example and also mention which engine you use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How glyphs are copied and pasted depends on the ToUnicode values of the font. Setting them is not trivial with the old type1 fonts. The easiest way to improve copy&paste and accessibility of math is to use lualatex and the unicode-math package and so an open-type math font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

$\sin(x) + \sin\bigl(x\bigr)$

\end{document}
```

The formula is then copied as

sin() + sin()

But you can't search for `sin(x)` as the real text is `sin()` unless your pdf viewer uses some heuristic to map the two x.

With pdflatex and the standard fonts you can  try the mmap package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mmap}
\begin{document}

$\sin(x) + \sin\bigl(x\bigr)$

\end{document}
```

This then copies as

```
sin(x) + sin
\bigl( 
x
\bigr)
```

Comment: Neither of these solutions is entirely ideal for me, but given the difficulties of mixing LaTeX and pdfs (e.g. making tagged pdfs) this is probably the best I can get right now. Thank you!