# Changing the behavior of $$ but not of $

Tags: math-mode, expansion

I am trying to set things up so that occurrences of `$$` are replaced by `\]` if in math mode, `\[` otherwise. My strategy is to make `$` active and have it behave differently depending on whether the following token is also a `$`. However, I cannot seem to make this work. Here is my attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\def\unactiveDollar{$}

\catcode`\$=\active
\def\activeDollar{$}

\def\executedollar{%
        \if\isDollar\activeDollar%
            \let\next=\executeDDollar%
        \else%
            \let\next=\unactiveDollar%
        \fi%
        \next%
    }
\def\executeDDollar{%
        \ifmmode%
            \let\next=\]%
        \else%
            \let\next=\[%
        \fi%
        \next%
        \let\absorbnext=
    }
\def${\futurelet\isDollar\executedollar}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[7]
$$\int x^2 \; dx = \frac{1}{3}x^3 + C$$
\lipsum[9]
%Make sure $ $ is not mistaken for $$:
It follows that $E = m c^2$ $\forall x \in X$.
\end{document}
```

The resulting error is

```
./doubledollar.tex:29: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\isDollar ->\if \isDollar 
                          \activeDollar \let \next =\executeDDollar \else \l...
l.29 $$
       \int x^2 \; dx = \frac{1}{3}x^3 + C$$
./doubledollar.tex:29:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Other variations (e.g., substituting `\ifx` for `\if`) give different errors or simply incorrect output, but nothing gets it right. And as far as I can tell, the key problem is that my method for determining whether the following token is a `$` (and absorbing it if so) simply does not work.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Additional note: An answer that throws an error whenever `$$` is used instead of other macros/environments (which must be able to use it internally) would also be acceptable, since it answers the titular question.

Comment: Motivation: In a document class I'm writing, direct use of `$$` changes the interline spacing of all subsequent text. So it's a much worse practice than usual.

Comment: Just ***never*** use `$$`. That's how.

Comment: looks a bit like [Can I redefine the dollar](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59980)

Comment: @egreg: I don't, but I'm writing a document class for the use of others who may be less enlightened, so it should at least throw an error to teach them.

Comment: Write in big flashing letters at the start of the doc: “Don't use `$$` or you'll be absorbed”.

Comment: Students trying to typeset their theses with minimal effort may not read the documentation.

Comment: @CharlesStaats just fail their thesis if they use `$$`:-) But if `$$` affects spacing opf following text do you redefine equation and eqnarray etc which just expand to `$$` ?

Comment: @David Carlisle: It has to do with grouping; `\equation`, etc. works (as much as it ever does), as does `{$$ ... $$}`. (There's an `\aftergroup` inside an `\everydisplay`.)

Comment: I'm usually mean to the users and include `\usepackage[all]{onlyamsmath}` in my templates. Then `$$` and `eqnarray` cause errors. Hard, but effective.

Comment: Note: In my previous comment, I wrote `\equation` when I meant `eqnarray`; in particular, I did not mean to imply that the `equation` environment is somehow flawed.

Answer (score 6):

You should use `\ifx` and not `\if`, that just compares character codes and does full expansion.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\let\unactiveDollar=$
\catcode`\$=\active

\def\executedollar{%
  \ifx\isDollar$%
    \let\next=\executeDDollar
  \else
    \let\next=\unactiveDollar
  \fi
  \next
}
\def\executeDDollar{%
  \ifmmode
    \let\next=\]%
  \else
    \let\next=\[%
  \fi
  \next
  \let\absorbnext=
}
\def${\futurelet\isDollar\executedollar}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[7]
$$\int x^2 \; dx = \frac{1}{3}x^3 + C$$
\lipsum[9]
%Make sure $ $ is not mistaken for $$:
It follows that $E = m c^2$ $\forall x \in X$.
\end{document}
```

Of course input such as

```
It follows that $E = m c^2$$\forall x \in X$.
```

which will produce weird errors, which might be cured with an `\ifinner` test.

Here's a similar version that does the check for a legal (albeit disputable) `$$`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\let\staats@inactivedollar=$
\catcode`\$=\active

\def\staats@execdollar{%
  \ifx\let@token$%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  \staats@execddollar
  \staats@inactivedollar
}
\def\staats@execddollar{%
  \ifmmode
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\ifinner
     \expandafter\@firstoftwo
   \else
     \expandafter\@secondoftwo
   \fi
   {\staats@inactivedollar}%
   {\]\let\staats@absorbnext= }}%
  {\[\let\staats@absorbnext= }%
}
\protected\def${\futurelet\let@token\staats@execdollar}

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[7]
$$\int x^2 \; dx = \frac{1}{3}x^3 + C$$
\lipsum[9]
%Make sure $ $ is not mistaken for $$:
It follows that $E = m c^2$ $\forall x \in X$.

It follows that $E = m c^2$$\forall x \in X$.
\end{document}
```

I fear that there are several things that can make this go wrong. The best is simply insisting that `$$` should never be used. Physical coercion might be fruitful. `;-)`

Comment: Lovely, but wouldn't `\usepackage[l2tabu]{nag}` be simpler?

Answer (score 6):

I believe the easiest way, though fairly draconian, is to place

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu,orthodox]{nag}
```

in your document class, or

```
\usepackage[l2tabu,orthodox]{nag}
```

in whatever auxiliary package you may be providing.

This will teach your users many things to be avoided, including `$$...$$`.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this answer by egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60395/484), together with the `\new@nextchar` macro from the `amsmath` package, I have an answer that seems to work, at least for this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\RequirePackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\def\unactiveDollar{$}
\catcode`\$=\active
\def\@DDollar${%
        \ifmmode%
            \let\next=\]%
        \else%
            \let\next=\[%
        \fi%
        \next%
    }
\protected\def${\new@ifnextchar$\@DDollar\unactiveDollar}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum*[7]
$$\int x^2 \; dx = \frac{1}{3}x^3 + C$$
\lipsum[9]
%Make sure $ $ is not mistaken for $$:
It follows that $E = m c^2$ $\forall x \in X$.
\end{document}
```

Question: Why is the definition of `$` protected? I copied this behavior because I assume there's a good reason for it, but this example works fine without it.

Comment: It's protected because `\new@ifnextchar` is not expandable, I guess. Also `\@DDollar` is not expandable. Place the unprotected version in an `\edef` and see what's happens...

Comment: It needs to be protected otherwise it'll go very wrong at the start of table cells, or if you go `\caption{ foo $x$}` or ...

Answer (score 0):

Here it is another answer. Instead of testing many things, after deciding if it starts inline or display math the `$`s are gobbled.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter
\catcode`\$=\active
\protected\def${\new@ifnextchar$\staats@dmath\staats@math}
\def\staats@math#1${\(#1\)}
\def\staats@dmath$#1$${\[#1\]}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Some math $x^2$

and a little more
$$ x^2 $$$x^2$$24$

\begin{figure}[h]
    \rule{2cm}{2cm}
    \caption{$x^2 +1$}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```