# How to redefine the behavior of dollar and then use dollar for \write18?

Tags: math-mode, shell-escape

I did what was suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59980/can-i-redefine-the-dollar) (I just want to use `$...$` instead of `\texttt{...}`, for the sake of experiment):

```
\documentclass{article}
\catcode`\$=\active
\gdef$#1${\texttt{#1}}
\begin{document}
Hello, $world$!
\immediate\write18{echo $HOME}
\end{document}
```

The `Hello, $world$` line works fine. However, `\write18` fails:

```
! Argument of $ has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.6 \immediate\write18{echo $HOME}
```

What is the right way to use `$` inside `\write18` in this case? I tried `\$`, no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo \string$HOME`

Or locally reset the catcode

Some other possiblities

```
1 xyz, /home/davidc
2 abc , string /home/davidc
3 abc , string /home/davidc
4 xyz, /home/davidc
5 xyz, /home/davidc
```

from

```
\documentclass{article}
\catcode`\$=\active
\gdef$#1${\texttt{#1}}
\def\abc{xyz}


\begin{document}
Hello, $world$!

\immediate\write18{echo 1  \abc, \string$HOME}

\immediate\write18{\detokenize{echo 2  \abc, $HOME}}

\immediate\write18{\unexpanded{echo 3  \abc, $HOME}}

{\catcode`\$=12
\immediate\write18{echo 4  \abc, $HOME}}

{\edef${\string$}
\immediate\write18{echo 5  \abc, $HOME}}


Hello, $world$!

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate to those who are not TeX experts yet, how exactly can I "locally reset the catcode"? :)

Comment: @yegor256 you show how to do that in your question.  `\catcode\`\$=\active` after the write to make it active and `\catcode\`\$=12` (say)  before to make it not active

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\detokenize`?