# Display all fractions generated by the \over command in red

Tags: fractions

In my copy-editing work I need to fix the layout of equations in the submitted papers.

To make it easier and faster it would be helpful to have the all fractions generated by the `\over` command displayed in red in the `.pdf` document.

Is there a way to achieve this? (Maybe redefining the `\over` command or adding something else in the preamble?)

Comment: `\over` is one of a `PlainTeX` tag, it's better to use `\frac`, if you ready to change to `\frac` some suggestions are there

Comment: I know, but I always found to complicate to change `\over` to `\frac` and I really don't need to do it.

Comment: if you use ansmath then frac is already redefined and over is defined to make a warning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can’t. In order to understand why, you need to know how `\over` works.

When TeX finds `\over` (or `\atop`, `\above`, `\overwithdelims`, `\atopwithdelims`, `\abovewithdelims`), it saves the math-list-so-far (the numerator) in a special stack and proceeds to build a new math list with what comes after `\over` (the denominator). When the current group ends, which might had been started with `$`, `$$`, `{` or `\left`, TeX finally knows what style the (generalized) fraction should be typeset in. At this point TeX can assign the correct math style to every item in the numerator and denominator so to actually append a fraction atom to the current math list.

As a consequence of this, you can do nothing more on the numerator, which has already been transformed in a math list, only awaiting to get style assignment to its items.

You might redefine `\over` to do the primitive `\over` and issue `\color{red}`, which will color the denominator. But beware that you need to read the two arguments in the case of `\...withdelims`.

This is similar to the strategy of `amsmath` tat saves `\over` as `\@@over` and redefines it to do `\@@over` and issue a warning. However, this warning is only issued once, but it's not difficult to modify the behavior so *every* use triggers the warning.

This is achieved in `\primfrac`:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\primfrac}[1]{%
  \PackageWarning{amsmath}{%
Foreign command \@backslashchar#1;\MessageBreak
\protect\frac\space or \protect\genfrac\space should be used instead%
\MessageBreak
  }
  \global\@xp\let\csname#1\@xp\endcsname\csname @@#1\endcsname
  \csname#1\endcsname
}
```

As you see, the line starting with `\global` redefines the command `\over` or sibling into the corresponding primitive. Just remove the `\global`.

Example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\primfrac}[1]{%
  \PackageWarning{amsmath}{%
Foreign command \@backslashchar#1;\MessageBreak
\protect\frac\space or \protect\genfrac\space should be used instead%
\MessageBreak
  }
  \@xp\let\csname#1\@xp\endcsname\csname @@#1\endcsname
  \csname#1\endcsname
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Here I use a fraction $a\over b$.

Here I use a generalized fraction $a\choose b$.

Another fraction $a\over b$.

\end{document}
```

This will produce in the log file

```
Package amsmath Warning: Foreign command \over;
(amsmath)                \frac or \genfrac should be used instead
(amsmath)                 on input line 18.


Package amsmath Warning: Foreign command \atopwithdelims;
(amsmath)                \frac or \genfrac should be used instead
(amsmath)                 on input line 20.


Package amsmath Warning: Foreign command \over;
(amsmath)                \frac or \genfrac should be used instead
(amsmath)                 on input line 22.
```

Only the first two would appear without removing `\global`.

However, you see that `\choose` triggers a warning about `\atopwithdelims` rather than `\choose`. This is because LaTeX adopts plain TeX's definition

```
\def\choose{\atopwithdelims()}
```

You may want to add

```
\let\@@choose\choose
\renewcommand{\choose}{\primfrac{choose}}
```

so you will also get

```
Package amsmath Warning: Foreign command \choose;
(amsmath)                \frac or \genfrac should be used instead
(amsmath)                 on input line 23.
```

in addition to the same warning for the subsequent usage of `\atopwithdelims`.

Answer (score 4):

I show that colorizing fractions declared by `\over` is possible. My experimental code is designed for OpTeX:

```
\def\scanmath#1#{\scanmathA{#1}}
\def\scanmathA#1#2{\addto\mlist{#1}\ifx\_fin#2\else
   {\def\mlist{}\checkover {#2}\_ea}\_ea\addto\_ea\mlist\_ea{\_ea{\mlist}}%
   \_ea \scanmath\_fi}
\def\checkover #1{\def\tmp{#1}\isinlist\tmp{\over}\iftrue
   \addto\mlist{\Red #1}\else \scanmath #1{\_fin}\fi}
\def\checkmath #1${\def\mlist{}\checkover{#1}\mlist$}
\def\checkdisplay #1$${\def\mlist{}\checkover{#1}\mlist$$}

\everydisplay{\checkdisplay}
$$
  \eqalign{
     a &= {1\over2} b + {4\over 5} \cr
     b &= {7\over {8\over 9}} }
$$

\everymath{\checkmath}
The text $a\over b$ and $c={d\over e}$.

\bye
```

The `\everydisplay` runs `\checkdisplay` and `\everymath` runs `\checkmath`. The whole math formula is read to the `#1` parameter and then it is checked if there is `\over` at "outer group level". If it is true then `\Red` is appended. Else we check if there is something like `...{...}...{...}...`.
Each such partial group is scanned separately and if there is `\over` then `\Red` is appended.

This experimental macro isn't universal. It doesn't check correctly the patterns like `\left(...\over...\right)`, you must to write
`\left({...\over...}\right)` instead it.

Comment: The approach is somewhat similar to [math mode - Can I redefine the dollar - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59980/can-i-redefine-the-dollar) but it uses everydisplay/everymath. If you have some command/environment that enters math mode (e.g. `\begin{align*}` in LaTeX) it doesn't work though.

Comment: // of course this answer also assumes the `\over` appears in "top-level" instead of hidden in some command, and there's no catcode-changing commands inside the math mode.

Comment: OpTeX doesn't use nothing like `\begin{align}`, so there is no problem. Catcode changing is not typical inside math mode. OP asks to colorize fractions created directly by `\over`, no by macros which "hide" the `\over` primitive.

Comment: OpTeX is not going to improve LaTeX.

Comment: OP doesn't mention LaTeX. OK, if my macro prototype should be used as starting point for LaTeX, more work have to be done.