# Apply macro to .tex file and get a new .tex file

Tags: macros

Are there a preprocessor for TeX, like for C/C++?

Are there a way to apply a macro to .tex file in order to generate new file?
For example, I have macro:

```
\renewcommand{asd}{some phrase here}
```

I have a .tex file:

```
bla-bla \asd bla-bla
```

I would like to get a new .tex file where all macros are replaced, and it will have this contents:

```
bla-bla some phrase here bla-bla
```

Comment: For a simple case, just use search and replace in your editor, or use sed. The only thing that can deal with every possibility is `TeX` itself.

Comment: Sorry, I can't, I've got a lot of files with complex macros... :(

Comment: This seems very similar to [LaTeX macro expander](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3174/)

Comment: i write the uk faq code in latex, and generate html on-line for whatever answer: just what you need.  however, the latex i write is highly stylised, and is full of annotations saying "don't let this line get too long" and the like.  there's some slick stuff in there, but i wouldn't want to be writing that sort of code for anything for which there was a timescale.  in my opinion, my situation (developed and improved since 1994) is analagous to yours.  you can make a transcript *only if* you wrote your latex with transcription in mind.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>This answer is based on a [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6525059/1443496).</sup>

You can actually use the C preprocessor if you like:

```
$ cat <<EOF | cpp -P | pdflatex
#define NAME Sean Allred
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Hello, NAME.
\end{document}
EOF
```

All of the features of the C preprocessor are available for use :-)