# TeX: reasons to start tokens using backslash

Tags: tex-core, knuth

I was wondering over the TeX programming language syntax. Is there a known reason why Knuth chose the backslash notation we all love and fear? It seams to me that most other contemporary languages (C, Prolog, Smalltalk, SQL) use syntaxes more alike as well as more easily read- and writeable, i.e. there was already common lexical scanning techniques around to use, not to end up with a cryptic notation. Is the reason commonly known?

Cheers

Comment: One obvious reason is that you are typesetting general text, so keywords such as "if" appearing in the text would need to be escaped. The operative word being "escape", for which the backslash is common.

Comment: The backslash character occurs exceedingly rarely in typographic *output*. Given that is shows up anyway on (US-layout) keyboards, it would seem to be a natural candidate to be designated as the "escape" character of the programming and typesetting language.

Comment: To quote the master: “TeX allows any character to be used for escapes, but the “backslash” character ‘\’ is usually adopted for this purpose, since backslashes are reasonably convenient to type and they are rarely needed in ordinary text.” from the TeXbook, Chapter 3: Controlling TeX

Comment: doh! Of course. I feel like an idiot now. Put it i an answer, @morbusg and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Henri and there's the reference.

Comment: @Mats If you want to interact with TeX via a normal programming language, take a look at LuaTeX.  It offers a Lua interface to TeX's typesetting engine.  (Please note, that LuaTeX is [not fully compatible](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222286/what-are-the-incompatibilities-of-pdftex-xetex-and-luatex) to Knuth TeX in all the nuisances).

Comment: @HenriMenke Was "nuisances" a Freudian slip for "nuances"? 8^b

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes You got me ;) Things like these happen to me quite often.  I should really practice vocabulary.

Comment: @HenriMenke The beauty of Freudian slips is that they reveal a lot of truth, as well a laugh.

Comment: @HenriMenke -- your "nuisances" has made my day.  thanks.

Comment: Closely related (maybe even duplicate) question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42301/why-doesnt-tex-latex-have-reasonable-defaults-in-certain-cases

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One obvious reason is that you are typesetting general text, so keywords such as "if" appearing in the text would need to be escaped. The operative word being "escape", for which the backslash is common.