# Struggling with getting equations to work

Tags: errors, equations, delimiters, undefined

I've had a hard look for answers to my problem but haven't managed to find any. This is driving me nuts.

```
    \underline{Copper:} \[3.142\times \(2.48\times \10^-^3)^\frac{2}{4}=4.83\times \10^-^6m^2\]

    \underline{Error\%:}  \[2(\frac{0.01}{2.48}\times \100)=0.81\%\]


    \underline{Copper-Nickel:} \[3.142\times \(2.2\times \10^-^3)^\frac{2}{4}=3.80\times \10^-^6m^2\]

    \underline{Error\%:} \[2(\frac{0.01}{2.20}\times \100)=0.90\%\]
```

I'm trying to get these equations to display in my report but I keep getting:

```
Bad math environment delimiter. \underline{Copper:} \[3.142\times \(
```

and

```
Undefined control sequence. ...ne{Copper:} \[3.142\times \(2.48\times \1
```

and

```
Double superscript. ...opper:} \[3.142\times \(2.48\times \10^-^
```

all over the place. I'm a total newbie at latex and this is the last thing I need to nail before I can submit my report but I cannot for the life of me figure out what is wrong. 
Any help appreciated.

Cheers

Oliver R

Comment: Please, show as your code as small complete document starting with `\documentclass{...}` nd ending with `\end{documenn}`, which cause your headache. From erors I suspect that you have somewhere wrongly nested math environments. And, welcome to TeX.SE

Comment: Replace \( and \) with \left ( and \right)

Comment: In `3.142\times \(2.48\times ` you have `\(`, which means math mode. We can deduce, that you simply want `(` here.

Comment: @ScottSeidman -- `\left` and `\right` are not needed here.  and in general, they should usually be avoided; see [Replace regular parenthesis with stretching versions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262752)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues with the code, taking the first line, what you probably want is `\underline{Copper:} \[3.142\times (2.48 \times 10^{-3})^{\frac{2}{4}}=4.83\times 10^{-6}m^2\]`.

[image]

You have some `\1` which is not a defined command - numbers can be written freely and not as macros, and a `\(` which starts inline maths environment which you don't want as `\[` has already started a display maths environment.  Finally `a^2` will print a superscript two, but `a^2^3` will not print 23 as superscript, what you are looking for is not `10^-^3` but `10^{-3}`.

For the purpose of printing units you may want to look into the [`siunitx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package.

Comment: Oh you beaut. That's solved it perfectly. Thanks a million.

Answer (score -1):

```
 \begin{document}
 {\underline{Copper:}} \[3.142\times\left ( 2.48 \times ^{-3} 
        \right)^{\frac{2}{4}}=4.83 \times 10^{-6} m^2\]

  \underline{Error\%:}  \[2\left(\frac{0.01}{2.48}\times 100\right)=0.81
  \%\]


 {\underline{Copper-Nickel:}} \[3.142\times \left(2.2\times 
   10{-^3}\right)^{\frac{2}{4}}=3.80\times 10^{-^6}m^2\]

  {\underline{Error\%:}} \[2(\frac{0.01}{2.20}\times 100)=0.90\%\]
  \end{document}
  % I hope this corrected version works for you.
```