# Delimiters: right height, right spacing and right behaviour with exponents

Tags: macros, delimiters

### Summary

I would like to have a efficient macro for parenthesis that I can use in all of my documents and macros.

---

## The issues and my attempts

### My first solution and its drawback

For parenthesis, I'm using the macro

```
\newcommand{\pth}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
```

But, in some cases, this macro induces extra horizontal space.
For instance,

```
\newcommand{\numberOfCycles}[2]{\mathscr{N}_{#1}\left(#2\right)}
```

produces a extra space after the "N", as shown here [image]

### My new solution and its drawback

[That's why I change](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2607/8323) my macro `\pth` to `\newPth` defined by

```
\newcommand{\newPth}[1]{\mathopen{}\left(#1\right)\mathclose{}}
```

But, this macro seems to be not compatible with exponents. See this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\pth}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\numberOfCycles}[2]{\mathrm{N}_{#1}\left(#2\right)}
\newcommand{\newPth}[1]{\mathopen{}\left(#1\right)\mathclose{}}

\begin{document}
\[
\numberOfCycles{i}{\sigma}
\]

\[
\newPth{1 + \frac{1}{n}}^n 
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

## My questions

- Generally, I would like to receive advice on theses issues.
- Does someone has a solution that would cover these two cases?

Comment: Sorry to have to rain on your parade, but there are tried-and-tested reasons for *not* using `\left` and `\right` indiscriminately each and every time a "fence" symbol is encountered. See, e.g., [Is it ever bad to use \left and \right?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173717/5001) as well as [Automatic left and right commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1742/5001) and [Macro for \left( and \right)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31526/5001).

Comment: see the mleftright package for a version of these macros that takes care of superscripts etc, but as a general advice not using left and right so often is a good idea.

Comment: Does one of the provided answers solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, I have accepted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I chose

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\myParentheses{\lparen}{\rparen}
\newcommand{\pth}[1]{\myParentheses*{#1}}
```

from the package `math tools`.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that your `\pth` macro is for special purposes, not for all accurrences of parentheses. You can try this:

```
\def\pth#1{\mathopen{}\mathord{\left(#1\right)}}
```