# \right] not displaying ]

Tags: equations, aligned

I have the following code:

```
\begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
     R^{1}_{\mu\nu} = \int & \frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4} \tr \left[ \frac{1}{\slashed{p} - \slashed{k}_2-m} \gamma_{5} \gamma_{\nu} \frac{1}{\slashed{p} - \slashed{q}-m} \gamma_{\mu} \\
    & - \frac{1}{\slashed{p} -m} \gamma_{5} \gamma_{\nu} \frac{1}{\slashed{p} - \slashed{k}_1-m} \gamma_{\mu} \right] 
 \end{aligned}   
\end{equation}
```

Here's a capture of what I get from it

[image: what I get]

As you can see, I'm using a long equation which splits in two with \begin{aligned}, and in the first line I have a \left[, which is displaying, but in the second line I have the \right], which isn't displayed on my final equation. You know what could be wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! `\left[` and `\right]` doesn't work over two (or more) lines. In such cases you should use `\bigl` (or `Bigl˛, `biggl`, etc) instead.

Comment: do not ignore error messages. if you get an error don't look at the pdf, ask about the message

Comment: If you decide to use auto scaling parentheses `\left(...\right)`, make sure you are aware of the issues: [here is a small list of issues](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12793/31283), [here's a discussion about spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2607/spacing-around-left-and-right), and [here's a demonstration why \left(\right) is problematic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58641/31283).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to use `\left[` and `\right]` inside an equation with linebreaks you have to use [package `breqn`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/breqn):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{slashed}
\usepackage{breqn}
\newcommand*{\tr}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{tr}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{dmath}
     R^{1}_{\mu\nu} = \int \frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4} \tr \left[ \frac{1}{\slashed{p} - \slashed{k}_2-m} \gamma_{5} \gamma_{\nu} \frac{1}{\slashed{p} - \slashed{q}-m} \gamma_{\mu} \\
     - \frac{1}{\slashed{p} -m} \gamma_{5} \gamma_{\nu} \frac{1}{\slashed{p} - \slashed{k}_1-m} \gamma_{\mu} \right] 
\end{dmath}
\end{document}
```

[image: using breqn]

An alternative would be, to use either `\right.` and `\left.`, but with the risk of having different size:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{slashed}
\newcommand*{\tr}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{tr}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
     R^{1}_{\mu\nu} = \int & \frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4} \tr \left[
                             \frac{1}{\slashed{p} - \slashed{k}_2-m}
                             \gamma_{5} \gamma_{\nu} \frac{1}{\slashed{p} -
                             \slashed{q}-m} \gamma_{\mu} \right. \\
    & \left. - \frac{1}{\slashed{p} -m} \gamma_{5} \gamma_{\nu} \frac{1}{\slashed{p} - \slashed{k}_1-m} \gamma_{\mu} \right] 
 \end{aligned}   
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: with \left. and \right.]

or to explicitly use a size:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{slashed}
\newcommand*{\tr}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{tr}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
     R^{1}_{\mu\nu} = \int & \frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4} \tr \biggl[
                             \frac{1}{\slashed{p} - \slashed{k}_2-m}
                             \gamma_{5} \gamma_{\nu} \frac{1}{\slashed{p} -
                             \slashed{q}-m} \gamma_{\mu} \\
    & - \frac{1}{\slashed{p} -m} \gamma_{5} \gamma_{\nu} \frac{1}{\slashed{p} - \slashed{k}_1-m} \gamma_{\mu} \biggr] 
 \end{aligned}   
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't know about line breaking issue. Thanks for making me knowing about that and breqn package.

Comment: thank you! it helped a lot