# automatic size adjustment for nested parentheses

Tags: math-mode, delimiters

As I prefer outer parentheses to grow larger in nested expressions, I happen to insert `\bigl` and `\bigr` and its larger cousins a lot. I have always wondered whether there is a way to do this automagically.

Inserting `\left` and `\right` prophylacticly before all opening and closing parentheses and hoping that it sorts things out doesn't do the trick in all cases as seen below.

The left column is without any size changing commands. The middle column as a `\left` `\right` pair at every parentheses/brace/bracket and the rightmost column shows my preferred version.

[image: example]

As seen in the middle column of the second and third line the `\left` and `\right` pair sometimes makes the outer parentheses larger, on the cost of an extra horizontal space between `\Pr` and `(`. The extra space is fine in case of really big opening parentheses but here I'd prefer the regular spacing.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
&1-(1-F(x))^n&&1-\left(1-F(x)\right)^n&&1-\bigl(1-F(x)\bigr)^n\\
&\Pr(X_{(1)}\le x)&&\Pr\left(X_{(1)}\le x\right)&&\Pr\bigl(X_{(1)}\le x\bigr)\\
&\mathbb{E}[\min\{X_1,X_2\}]&&\mathbb{E}\left[\min\left\{X_1,X_2\right\}\right]&&\mathbb{E}\bigl[\min\left\{X_1,X_2\right\}\bigr]\\
&\left(\pi-\arccos(\frac{y}{r})\right)&&(\pi-\arccos\left(\frac{y}{r}\right))&&\left(\pi-\arccos \left(\frac{y}{r}\right)\right)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

As mathematical expressions can be arbitrarly complex there is probably no general way to do this. But I’m not asking for a solution of the general case. A partial solution that works in the simple cases shown above would be a big help. The simple rule could be, that parentheses never shrink below the size of an inner pair. Of course you can immediately think of extensions like a `\mid` in a conditional expectation that grows with the size of the expectation’s brackets.

What is your preference regarding the size of nested parentheses? Is there a better way to archieve your preferred style despite inserting `\bigl` `\bigr` manually?

---

EDIT:

A colleague pointed me to section 8.3 of Herbert Voß’ [mathmode](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/voss-mathmode) document where size problems with parentheses are solved by playing with two TeX parameters within a group around the expression in question. This led naturally to appendix G of the TeXbook where the mechanics of `\delimitershortfall` and `\delimiterfactor` are explained.

`\delimitershortfall` specifies the maximum space not covered by a delimiter (default 5pt)
and
`\delimiterfactor` is the ratio for variable delimiters, times 1000 (default 901).

I used them to implement the *never shrink below a subformular size* idea from above by setting the shortfall to 0pt and the ratio to 1.0.

[image: example]

While it works nicely in line one and three, in line two and four the parentheses now grow too much, and still there is the extra horizontal space introduced by `\left`.

Comment: I tend to use square brackets when this is causing a problem. In general I use `left` and `right` most of the time and let the equations be as wide as they need to be. Is there a particular reason that it bothers you?

Comment: @Mark In words like _Schifffahrt_ a sequence of the same letter looks strange. I think it is the same with a sequence of same size  parentheses _(((_. Of course I could use  _[{(_ but I find the variation in the size nicer to look at.

Comment: I see now. I think most cases for me naturally go away when I break equations over lines. LaTeX probably already has the best default behaviour, but maybe it is worth exploring.

Comment: Journals tend to recommend mixing the parentheses to save some space. Also one should be a bit careful about the sizes. Sometimes there is no need to use huge parentheses around a long equation, if the large part is in the middle and it is not large (above/below) at the ends. I tend to recommend users to scale such that it is clear what is being fenced in, but also such that the parentheses do not dominate the expression.

Comment: Definitely, this would require some kind of two-pass system, since when we encounter the first opening bracket, we don't know yet whether there'll be more.  But this does not necessarily mean two LaTeX passes and messing with the aux file, it would be enough to analyze the token list constituting the equation beforehand.  Maybe `l3regexp` would help?  Notice that in general this seems to be one of these problems where computers cannot solve all possible cases (because of the complicated aesthetical issues involved).

Comment: @mbork: Maybe I don't quite understand what you mean, but isn't the `\left...\right` mechanism from the TeX core already a two-pass system? At the opening `\left`, TeX doesn't know yet what size the delimiter should have. Moreover, nesting  `\left...\right` also works.

Comment: Regarding the extra space around `\left...\right` see [Spacing around \left and \right](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2607).

Comment: @uli: what is the font used in the image in the question? It looks much nicer than the standard TeX font.

Comment: @Mohan: It is the wonderful work of [Johannes Küster](http://www.typoma.de/en/fonts.html), who created Minion Math as a companion to Robert Slimbach’s Minion.

Comment: I'm sorry for a foolish question, but, before your first table, you say "The middle column [h]as a `\left` `\right` pair at every parentheses/brace/bracket and the rightmost column shows my preferred version"; and yet the middle column of the $(\pi - \arccos(y/r))$ row has only one `\left` `\right` pair for two parentheses, whereas the rightmost column has two `\left` `\right` pairs.  Is this what was intended?

Comment: @l-spice Your question is not foolish, indeed there is a '\left \right'-pair missing.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The `nath` package with `\delimgrowth=1` is very close to your preferred style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{nath}
\delimgrowth=1

\begin{document}
  \begin{equation}
     1 - (1-F(x))^n \\
     \Pr(X_{(1)} \le x) \\
     \mathbb{E}[\min\{X_1, X_2\} ] \\
     ( \pi - \arccos (\frac {y}{r}) )
  \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Read the [nath guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/nath/nathguide.pdf) for details, especially the part about incompatibility with `amsmath`.

Comment: @Herbert, Aditya if I could only accept both answers. But as I have to choose... I love the `nath` solution for its easier to read latex source, nothing is cluttered with `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: Does it work in the beamer class? (asking because it crashed my beamer, could be an incompatibility with another package though) Thanks.

Answer (score 38):

Use it this way with a small negative space between two large parentheses:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\delimitershortfall=-1pt
\begin{align*}
\left(\pi-\arccos \left(\frac{y}{r}\right)\right)\\
\left(\pi-\arccos \left(\frac{y}{r}\right)\!\right)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

here is an idea how it can be done with a double `((` and/or `))`. It is also possible to use `\left((...(`  and a `\right))...)`. only the number of `\left` and `\right` parentheses must correspond to each other

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\delimitershortfall=-1pt
\let\Right\right
\let\Left\left
\makeatletter
\def\right#1{\Right#1\@ifnextchar){\!\right}{}}
\def\left#1{\Left#1\@ifnextchar({\!\left}{}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\left(\pi-\arccos \left(\frac{y}{r}\right)\right)\\
\left(\pi-\arccos \left(\frac{y}{r}\right))\\
\left((\pi-\arccos \left(\frac{y}{r}\right)))\\
\left(\left(x + \frac12\right)\arccos(\pi)\right)\\
\left((x + \frac12\right)\arccos(\pi)\right)
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you think of a way to automate this? Do you think `\mathinner` could somehow be helpful here?

Comment: @morbusg: I edited my answer

Comment: Yeah, I noticed (and your reply to the `\mathinner` as well; thanks for that!), very nice! (+1)

Answer (score 7):

You can do this without using external packages, which can simplify things a bit if the solution needs to work e.g. in KaTeX. You can define your own "growing parenthesis" command by using invisibe subscripts around the parenthesis' contents:

```
\newcommand{\paren}[1]{\mathopen{}\left( {#1}_{{}_{}}\,\negthickspace\right)\mathclose{}}
\newcommand{\bracket}[1]{\mathopen{}\left[ {#1}_{{}_{}}\,\negthickspace\right]\mathclose{}}
```

Which gets you exactly the look you want when used at the right places (middle column was modified):

```
\begin{aligned}
&1-(1-F(x))^n&&1-\paren{1-F(x)}^n&&1-\bigl(1-F(x)\bigr)^n\\
&\Pr(X_{(1)}\le x)&&\Pr\left(X_{(1)}\le x\right)&&\Pr\bigl(X_{(1)}\le x\bigr)\\
&\mathbb{E}[\min\{X_1,X_2\}]&&\mathbb{E}\bracket{\min\left\{X_1,X_2\right\}}&&\mathbb{E}\bigl[\min\left\{X_1,X_2\right\}\bigr]\\
&\left(\pi-\arccos(\frac{y}{r})\right)&&\left(\pi-\arccos\left(\frac{y}{r}\right)\right)&&\left(\pi-\arccos \left(\frac{y}{r}\right)\right)
\end{aligned}
\[ \paren{\paren{\paren{\paren{\paren{}}}}} \]
\[ \bracket{\bracket{\bracket{\bracket{\bracket{}}}}} \]
```

[image: aligned]

Comment: In my case there are a problem with fractions and \paren when is added an exponent.

Answer (score 4):

My current solution is to use the `mathtools` macro `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`

e.g. `\DeclarePairedDelimiter\brac{(}{)}` allows me to use `\brac*{stuff}` for autoexpanding brackets. This probably is preferable to `nath` with extremely large documents (the readme for `nath` suggests that it takes up to 3 times the compile time!)

Of course it's somewhat annoying to have to star the command every time, so you can swap the behavior, detailed here: [Easily change behavior of \DeclarePairedDelimiter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94410/easily-change-behavior-of-declarepaireddelimiter)

Also, `nath` is notorious for being incompatable with almost all math related packages, so it's not actually useful at all.

Answer (score 2):

What I do is declaring a parenthis-function that uses `\vphantom` with `\raisebox` to add extra height to the outer delimiter.

The solution is not pretty:

- I use `\mathop` because else `\vphantom` does not work and then add negative space to counter the extra space that `\mathop` adds.
- Also inside `\raisebox` you need to use `\( \)` to get into mathmode and `\displaystyle` to get the right virtual height

But it works for me and you can still tweak `\delimtershortfall` and `\delimiterfactor` to your liking (if you then also adjust the raise in `\raisebox`).
Also you can change the value in `\raisebox` to adjust the growth of the delimiters.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mleftright}


\global\delimitershortfall=5.5pt
\global\delimiterfactor=880
\renewcommand*{\left}{\mleft}
\renewcommand*{\right}{\mright}
\newcommand{\braced}[1]
    { \left( #1 \right) 
        \mskip-1.5mu \vphantom{ \mathop{
           \raisebox{3pt}{ \(\left(\displaystyle #1 \right)\) } } }
    }

\begin{document}
    \[
    \braced{ x + \braced{\braced{ y }} }
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: is it bad behavior that i postet this exact same answer under another question that i regard a pulicate of this one?