# Are nath and xcolor incompatible?

Tags: errors, color, incompatibility

I have a file that compiles fine. It uses `nath` and `color` packages:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{nath}
\delimgrowth=1

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 A \Rightarrow (B)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

But as soon as I try to color `(B)`, I get an error `extra {`. The complete file (which does not compile) is:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{nath}
\delimgrowth=1

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 A \Rightarrow {\color{red}(B)}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Removing the `nath` package and  `\delimgrowth` command fixes the error. 
The following code compiles fine.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 A \Rightarrow {\color{red}(B)}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Also, If I remove the braces around `B`, the error is gone. The following code compiles fine:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{nath}
\delimgrowth=1

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 A \Rightarrow {\color{red}B}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Thanks to @egreg for pointing out that `nath` does not like paretheses hidden away inside braces. The following code also does not compile:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{nath}
\delimgrowth=1

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 A \Rightarrow {(B)}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

So, my question is: Is there a way to have colored equations in a file that uses `nath` to automatically resize nested parentheses?

I learned about the `nath` package from [automatic size adjustment for nested parentheses](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36039/automatic-size-adjustment-for-nested-parentheses).

Comment: Please make a complete small document that shows all the packages loaded so the problem may be reproduced.

Comment: Try `\textcolor{red}{(B)}` instead of `{\color{red}(B)}`

Comment: @egreg That does not fix the error. Thanks anyways

Comment: You get the same error with `A \Rightarrow {(B)}` and without loading `color`. So this is a problem of `nath` that doesn't like parentheses hidden by braces.

Answer (score 6):

You get the same error with the following document:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{nath}
\delimgrowth=1

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 A \Rightarrow {(B)}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

with or without `\delimgrowth`, because `nath` doesn't like the parentheses to be hidden inside braces.

You can go around this limitation like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{nath}
\delimgrowth=1

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 A \Rightarrow \textcolor{red}{\mbox{$(B)$}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

but I don't know if this is useful for your real case.

Comment: Thanks @egreg . It compiles and looks good. However, This solution turns off nath's automatic parenthesis size adjustment inside the mbox part. This might not be desirable in general

Comment: @Abhishek I know. I never use `nath` because it wants to be *too* smart.

Comment: Is there any other package that can do automatic nested parenthesis size adjustment for me?

Comment: @Abhishek Maybe I'm old fashioned, but I like to choose by myself when growing fences or two story fractions should be used.