# Sloppy \left and \right?

Tags: math-mode, formatting, delimiters

The `\left` and `\right` commands often produce improvidently large delimiters.  It almost always looks better to use delimiters that are just slightly too small than delimiters that are too large. With computer modern, the results are usually bearable, but with (for example) the `mathdesign` package using charter font, the delimiter sizing is intolerable.  For instance, the following code produces vertical bars around y that are much larger than x:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}

\begin{document}

    It would be nice if these were the same size:
    \[ \left|x\right| \quad \left|y\right| \]
    It would be even better if
    \[\left|x^{2^3}\right| \quad \text{ looked like } \quad \bigl| x^{2^3}\bigr|\]

\end{document}
```

An image of the result:

[image]

So now the question: Any ideas on how to produce sloppy `\left` and `\right` commands (say, `\sleft` and `\sright`) that allows a little bit of overhang?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: Thanks, @Corentin, and also for the screen shot. I'll make sure to format all code in future posts.

Comment: You should consider using `\big` (and friends). Also, [`scalerel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/scalerel) *might* be what you're after.

Comment: @Werner: I agree that `\big`, etc., are good for tuning a final draft. But `\left` and `\right` should get me within the ballpark so that most equations don't need fine tuning. That's the whole point of these commands, no?

Comment: Well, actually... no.  The TeXbook has a bunch of examples where `\left` and `\right` give clearly *wrong* size (sometimes too big, sometimes too small).  IMHO, their main use is for delimiters bigger than `\Bigg...`.  Equations *will* need tuning if you want them too look good anyway.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\delimitershortfall=10pt
\delimiterfactor=750
\begin{document}

    It would be nice if these were the same size:
    \[ \left|x\right| \quad \left|y\right| \]
    It would be even better if
    \[\left|x^{2^3}\right| \quad \text{ looked like } \quad \bigl| x^{2^3}\bigr|\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is perfect, but `\delimiterfactor=850` works even better.  After seeing the command names, here is a similar post with additional information: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36039/automatic-size-adjustment-for-nested-parentheses

Comment: An explanation what those commands do would be helpful.