# Less aggressive automatic paren stretching with \left

Tags: math-mode, brackets, delimiters

`\left` and `\right` are convenient but sometimes they're a bit overeager in stretching the parentheses.  In that case we can manually use `\bigl`, `\Bigl`, etc.

I have defined a new command like this

```
\newcommand{\avg}[1]{\ensuremath{\left\langle #1 \right\ranlge}}
```

I would like this command to have automatic stretching, but I don't want this mechanism to kick in too early.  With this definition, `\avg{x^2}` already has bigger brackets than `\avg{x}`.  I would prefer not to use stretching at this level at all.  I would, however, like it to use stretching for `\avg{\frac{x}{2}}` in display mode.  Something like this would be nice: 1. don't stretch at all in inline math 2. do stretch as normal above a certain size threshold in display math, but not below this threshold.

Is there an *easy* way to implement this?  Perhaps it's less trouble to use `\left\langle ... \right\rangle` manually when I really need stretching.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Sloppy `\left` and `\right`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102157/5764)

Comment: @Werner It's not a duplicate.  I can accept "this is too much trouble to do" as an answer, but note that I did mention `\bigl` et al in the question.  This question is about how to set a size threshold for *automatic* resizing below which brackets are not resized at all.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a fairly naive solution that has not been extensively tested:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathstyle}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mathstyle
\usepackage{multido}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multido (just for this example)
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\getmathstyle}{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78874/5764
  \global\edef\curmathstyle{%
    \expandafter\@gobble\mathchoice{\@@displaystyle}{\@@textstyle}{\@@scriptstyle}{\@@scriptscriptstyle}}
}
\makeatother
\let\oldleft\left
\def\left#1#2\right#3{
  \getmathstyle\sbox0{$\curmathstyle#2$}
  \ifdim\ht0<20pt\relax
    #1#2#3
  \else
    \oldleft#1#2\right#3
  \fi
}
\begin{document}

$\multido{\i=10+2}{10}{
  \begin{array}{c}
    \texttt{\i pt} \\
    \left(\rule{1pt}{\i pt}\right)%
    \rule[-30pt]{0pt}{60pt}% Add a strut for visual clarity
  \end{array}
}$

\end{document}
```

The threshold for switching to the regular `\left`...`\right` usage is `20pt` (changeable, of course). I'm not comfortable dealing with TeX primitives, so use of this solution is heavily cautioned.

The choice of math style capture is taken from [How to capture the current math style?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78872/5764)

Answer (score 6):

[image]

You can set `\delimiterfactor` to delay the start of stretching, however even if the brackets don't stretch, `\left` `\right` makes a math inner atom which affects the horizontal spacing (and prevents linebreaking).

(plain tex)

```
\def\x#1{\left({\vrule height#1pt}_{#1}a+b\right)}

$\x{08}\x{10}\x{12}\x{14}\x{16}\x{20}\x{24}$

{\delimiterfactor400
\delimitershortfall\maxdimen
$\x{08}\x{10}\x{12}\x{14}\x{16}\x{20}\x{24}$
}

\def\x#1{({\vrule height#1pt}_{#1}a+b)}
$\x{08}\x{10}\x{12}\x{14}\x{16}\x{20}\x{24}$

\bye
```

In a real example you would set `\delimitershortfall` to a smaller length to stop the brackets getting too small, set to `\maxdimen` here to highlight the effect.