# Mathpazo has broken \left and \right

Tags: fonts, math-mode, fontsize, mathpazo

If I use `mathpazo` then it seems that `\left\Vert` and `\right\Vert` generate the wrong size in one case:

```
 \documentclass[11pt]{article}
 \usepackage{mathpazo}
 \begin{document}
 {\Large $\left\Vert X_f\right\Vert$}
 {\large $\left\Vert X_f\right\Vert$}
 {\normalsize $\left\Vert X_f\right\Vert$}
 {\small $\left\Vert X_f\right\Vert$}
 {\footnotesize $\left\Vert X_f\right\Vert$}
 {\scriptsize $\left\Vert X_f\right\Vert$}
 {\tiny $\left\Vert X_f\right\Vert$}
 \end{document}
```

Notice how the fourth `\Vert` is the wrong size:

[image]

Is this a bug or a feature? And how to I get rid of it? Saying "do not use `\left` and `\right`" is not a valid answer until you also suggest how I might get the following macro working without them:

```
\newcommand{\trunc}[2]{\mathopen{}\left\Vert #2\right\Vert_{#1}\mathclose{}}
```

It has to be one macro, the book is already written using it. As far as I am concerned this is not my fault, but that of `mathpazo`.

Comment: How to get rid of it? Do not use `\left` and `\right`, they produce an extra horizontal space and they quite often produce too large delimiters.

Comment: Ok but what should I use then? This is for a macro which has to automagically pick the correct size of `\Vert` depending on the size of the argument. Let me amend the question.

Comment: By the way, this is not something special about `\Vert` -- it applies to all other delimiters too, at least all the ones I've tried.

Comment: in my opinion, only the first three and the next-to-last look decent.  using `\smash[b]` on *only* the subscript (requires `amsmath`) would be an improvement, but it may not be practical.  i'll take a closer look, with other delimiters as well as `\Vert` and parentheses (as in your original formulation).

Comment: You'll find a solution in <http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102157/sloppy-left-and-right>. The commands you want are `\delimitershortfall=10pt` and `\delimiterfactor=750`. This is not just a problem with `mathpazo`, try compiling with `\usepackage{mathpazo}` removed. Then the scriptsize and tiny delimeters are poorly sized. Compiling the document at 10,11 and 12pt produces surprising results, with `mathpazo` and also without `mathpazo`.

Comment: It seems to be a specific problem with the `f` subscript - replacing it with `g` does not display such drastic behaviour.

Comment: I don't suppose anyone would be interested in explaining what is causing this problem, and why `\delimiterfactor` and `\delimitershortfall` fix it?  Personally, I would really like to understand, not just slap on a quick fix that acts like magic to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the `nath` or the `MnSymbol` packages. Beware that they have to be loaded after all packages that define math stuff (and might be incompatible with some of them).

Your MWE (I replaced `\left\Vert` with `\lVert` and `\right\Vert` with `\rVert`)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{nath}
\begin{document}
{\Large $\lVert X_f\rVert$}
{\large $\lVert X_f\rVert$}
{\normalsize $\lVert X_f\rVert$}
{\small $\lVert X_f\rVert$}
{\footnotesize $\lVert X_f\rVert$}
{\scriptsize $\lVert X_f\rVert$}
{\tiny $\lVert X_f\rVert$}
\end{document}
```

with `nath` package, for example, will produce

[image]

A similar result is obtained with `MnSymbol`.