# Universal Parentheses

Tags: brackets

I know it's a bit of an odd request but it is one to which the solution would save me a lot of time.

I write a lot of documents in LaTex (especially maths - no surprise) and I prefer the look of

```
$\left(\right)$
```

parentheses on a lot of things because they actually encompass the things inside. For example:

```
$\deg\left(m_{\alpha_{1}/K}\right)$
```

looks better than

```
$\deg(m_{\alpha_{1}/K})$
```

in my opinion.

Unfortunately, writing \left and \right every time is a bit tiresome.

Is there any way that I can make them all do it automatically? There is a solution here: [automatic size adjustment for nested parentheses](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36039/automatic-size-adjustment-for-nested-parentheses) but it interferes with tikz (presumably because it affects the parentheses).

I tried a solution like

```
$\newcommand{\(}{\left(}$
```

but LaTeX didn't like that.

Comment: Note that `\(` is already an existing, important LaTeX command for entering textstyle math mode, and should not be usurped.

Comment: Note that automatic resizing is not generally recommended as they can often get too large, e.g. `\left(\sum_i\right)` looks ridiculous, and used in inline math, they can easily grow so much that they interfere with line spacing.

Comment: Pardon me if this isn't what you're looking for, but to offer a simple solution: have you considered [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) and just doing something like `Alt + Shift + (` > `\left`?

Comment: @LukeSawczak Who said anything about the asker using Windows?

Comment: @DavidRicherby one does not need Windows to define shortcuts. One can easily configure editors like [TeXStudio](http://www.texstudio.org/) which run on other platforms, too, to achieve that behaviour.

Comment: another drawback might be that a linebreak is not possible between `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: @jakun The comment I was replying to suggested a specific piece of software, which is only available on Windows.

Comment: Somewhat related: [math mode - Automatic left and right commands - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1742/automatic-left-and-right-commands)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Making `(` active is not really a solution because it is used in so many other ways, but here is how it would be done.

To help in this regard. I create `\pactive` to make `(` active which, if used inside a group like an equation, can revert `(` to its normal definition after the group is closed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\svlp(
\catcode`(=\active %
\def(#1){\left\svlp#1\right)}
\catcode`(=12 %
\newcommand\pactive{\catcode`(=\active }
\begin{document}
\[
\pactive
\deg(m_{\alpha_{1}/K}) + (\frac{a}{x+c})
\]
Normal use of ( or even \fbox{\makebox(20,30){test}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The OP asks about automating the invocation of `\pactive`.  Again, I don't recommend it, because there may be need in math mode to use the `()` set as an argument to some macro.  But the use of

```
\everymath{\pactive}
\everydisplay{\pactive}
```

will accomplish it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\svlp(
\catcode`(=\active %
\def(#1){\left\svlp#1\right)}
\catcode`(=12 %
\newcommand\pactive{\catcode`(=\active }
\everymath{\pactive}
\everydisplay{\pactive}
\begin{document}
\[
%\pactive
\deg(m_{\alpha_{1}/K}) + (\frac{a}{x+c})
\]
Normal use of ( or even \fbox{\makebox(20,30){test}}

\(
%\pactive
\deg(m_{\alpha_{1}/K}) + (\frac{a}{x+c})
\)
Normal use of ( or even \fbox{\makebox(20,30){test}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks to Timm for reminding that, if one really wants to automate this, then one should have handy the override macro

```
\newcommand\pinactive{\catcode`(=12 }
```

Comment: Is there no way to restrict this active behaviour to the math mode? _Edit:_ I guess your edit is a suitable solution.

Comment: This is definitely getting there. I know this is asking a lot now but is there a way to do this without having to put `\pactive` at the beginning of every math mode?

For instance, is it possible to define the group you are opening to have `\pactive` automatically?

Comment: @PercyF2519 If I can think of a way, I will post it an notify you.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will leave the question 'unanswered' for now. Although it feels so close to begin  solved.

Comment: @PercyF2519 Tahdah!: `\everymath{\pactive}
\everydisplay{\pactive}`

Comment: After some preliminary testing that looks perfect. You are a genius and I love you for it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Would it be reasonable to define a `\pinactive` command to prevent the problem you mentioned in the second part of your answer _(I assume ``\newcommand\pinactive{\catcode`(=12}`` would do the trick, however I'm not sure about the 12)_?

Comment: @Timm Yes it would certainly be reasonable to define \newcommand\pinactive{\catcode`(=12 }, the only difference from yours is a space after the 12, which I seem to recall egreg always stressed could be important in some circumstances that elude me.

Comment: Try `\mbox{$\displaystyle(\frac{1}{2}$}`

Comment: @egreg If you are referring to the requirement that parens be matched in math mode, I thought that was understood, given that they are converted into a `\left...\right` pair.  But if you think I should explicitly state it??

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I forgot the closing parenthesis, sorry; but the problem is that `(` and `)` will not be active in that context.

Comment: @egreg Is it because the `(` is absorbed as a catcode 12 argument to `\mbox`?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Yes, precisely.

Answer (score 17):

An easy solution would just be to use the `qty` command from the `physics` package. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}
\begin{document}
With \texttt{qty}:
\[
\qty(m_{\frac\alpha\beta}) + \qty(\frac{1}{x+y}) + \qty(\int^{\infty}_{0} x^2 \dd{x})
\]

Without \texttt{qty}:
\[
(m_{\frac\alpha\beta}) + (\frac{1}{x+y}) + (\int^{\infty}_{0} x^2 \dd{x})
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: with and without qty]

Comment: This is very elegant. I assume there is no way of making this a universal operation within math mode?

Comment: Not that I know of. The solution I propose here is merely a working alternative to what you were trying to implement. :)

Comment: It is very nice - much nicer than the standard`\left(` `\right)` method.

Answer (score 8):

It's definitely a bad idea, but if you really want to get ugly documents, here it is. `;-)`

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\extlparen}{\left\delimiter"4028300 }
\newcommand{\extrparen}{\right\delimiter"5029301 }
\begingroup\lccode`~=`( \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\extlparen
\begingroup\lccode`~=`) \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\extrparen

\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`(="8000 \mathcode`)="8000 }

\begin{document}
\[
\deg(m_{\alpha_{1}/K})+(\sum_{i=1}^n i^2)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The same with proper markup:

```
\[
\deg(m_{\alpha_{1}/K})+\biggl(\,\sum_{i=1}^n i^2\biggr)
\]
```

[image]

The parentheses are much better in the second case than in the top one.

Comment: Really? Honestly, I prefer the top case. Except the gap between `deg` and the parenthesis - but that is an issue I can solve.

Comment: @PercyF2519 then try `\left(\sum_{\substack{j<i\\ i\in A}}\right)`, trust us it is not a good idea in general.

Answer (score 3):

While you ask about an automatic solution to this, i would still like to present a systematic Approach to this. The `mathtools` package allows you to define commands with *paired delimiters*. The starred variants of the command (the one you created) adds a `\left` and a `\right`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
% 'braced' fraction:
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\bfrac[2]{(}{)}{\frac{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        \bfrac{a}{x + c} + \bfrac*{a}{x + c}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Sorry, i can't post a screenshot now, but the first fraction puts normal braces, the second one bigger ones (scaled with `\left` and `\right`).

Note that the starred Version of `\bfrac` was not defined.

One can do a lot of stuff with this, i recommend reading the respective part in the `mathtools` manual.

Answer (score 3):

I think the `mathtools` package gives the perfect solution to the original problem.  You put

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\paren{\lparen}{\rparen}

\paren*{\frac12}
```

The starred version allows the parentheses grow automatically.  If you do not like how the parenthesis grows, you can specify the exact size

```
\paren[\Big]{\frac12}
```

Here is a full example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\paren}{\lparen}{\rparen}

\begin{document}
Here with the starred version of the command, the parentheses grow
automatically, the nonstarred just gives the usual parens, and in the
third version with the 'Big' option, you specify the size by hand.  

\begin{equation*}
  \paren*{\frac12} \quad \paren{\frac12} \quad \paren[\Big]{\frac12} 
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

You can see the output at 
http://wd369.csi.hu/apu/paren.png

Comment: I don't understand the usage of `(` and `)` vs. `\lparen` and `\rparen`. Are they interchangable in `DeclarePairedDelimiter`? If used on their own, `\lparen` and `\rparen` are (according to the docs) equivalent to `\left(` and `\right)`, so should scale automatically on their own. Why do we then still need the starred variant of `\paren`?

Comment: It's explained in section 3.7.1 of the `mathtools` documentation http://www.texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mathtools/mathtools.pdf  why use commands instead of ( and ). And no, `\lparen` is not the same as `\left(` .  It doesn't grow.  The use of `\paren` makes your code more comapct and intuitive especially if you must nest these.

Comment: In section 3.7.1, all it says is that `\lparen` is simply a shorthand for `\left(`. The way I read it, all that section says it that they *are* equivalent. So my question about the starred variant still stands, I see no difference.

Comment: The last sentence of section 3.7.1 says "Some packages need command names to work with so `mathtools` defines thecommands `\lparen` and `\rparen` to represent the left and right parenthesis resp".   So *command names*  are needed instead of just symbols like (.

Comment: Also, when do you type less `\paren*{ \frac12 }` or `\left( \frac12 \right)`

Answer (score 1):

Using plain TeX commands inside a LaTeX document, this is pretty straightforward:

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\lparen(
\let\rparen)
\catcode`(=\active
\catcode`)=\active
\def({\ifmmode\left\fi\lparen}
\def){\ifmmode\right\fi\rparen}

\begin{document}

\[
  \deg(m_{\alpha_{1}/K})+(\sum_{i=1}^n i^2)
\]

In the rare case that you need normal parentheses:

\[
  \deg\lparen m_{\alpha_{1}/K}\rparen+\lparen\sum_{i=1}^n i^2\rparen
\]

This is (pretty) normal text.

\end{document}
```

It's just making `\lparen` an alias for an ordinary parenthesis and then redefining it. After that, you can still use the `\lparen` macro, just in case you don't like the active parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the `nath` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nath}
\begin{document}
\(
\deg(\frac{m_{\alpha_{1}}}{K}) + (\sum_{i=1}^n i^2)
\)
\[
\deg(\frac{m_{\alpha_{1}}}{K}) + (\sum_{i=1}^n i^2)
\]
\end{document}
```

which gives:
[image]

Note that the scaling of delimiters is better than the default scaling with `\left( ... \right)`. As an added bonus, `\frac` behaves intelligently in inline vs display mode.

Comment: Unfortunately, `nath` is incompatible with so many packages…

Comment: Only with `amsmath`; what else :-) It still appears to be a better solution than making `(` active and mapping it to `\left(`.

Comment: Incompatibility with amsmath is something of a deal-breaker for a mathematics package, no?

Comment: @DavidRicherby: It depends. I believe that `nath` works if you do not use multiline display environments from `amsmath`. It is not an ideal solution but a trade-off. For some people, the drawbacks outweigh the gains; but for others it is the other way round. Depends on what type of math environment you need. I use `nath` for notes, assignment, and exams for undergrad level EE courses, where `nath` gives correct (or rather better than default) scaling of delimiters without too much thought. For research papers, I make heavy use to amsmath and don't use nath. So, .... it depends.

Answer (score 1):

I often use the xparse package to define operators that can take parenthesized input, but if they don't find that input, they treat themselves as not having any input.

[image: Image of the tex output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}
\RenewDocumentCommand\deg{d()}{\ensuremath{\operatorname{deg}\IfValueT{#1}{\left(#1\right)}}}
\begin{document}
The degree \(\deg\) of the vector bundle \(V\) is 
\[
\deg(V) = 1.
\]
Its slope is \(\deg/\operatorname{rank}\).
\end{document}
```

Comment: why `\ensuremath` when you are always using it in math mode?

Answer (score 0):

Something that I use is the following:

```
\newcommand\del[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
\newcommand\sbr[1]{\left[ #1 \right]}
\newcommand\cbr[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}
\newcommand\abr[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
```

Then in the code, one can just use `\del{ ... }` and get delimiters. Also I can just change `del` to `sbr` if I want to have square brackets.

The package `commath` also defines very similar commands, but that package has very mixed reviews.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use the vim-latex suite. It makes your life easier in many ways, and on of them is the automatic replacement for brackets, underscores and circumflexes if typed doubled, so that `((` becomes `\left(  \right)<++>`, as well as for example `__` becomes `_{}<++>`.

So it's always you who decides if to use the scaled version, but if you want it, it's only a second opening bracket away.

Answer (score 0):

May not be the best solution at all but you can try editing your document with TexStudio. It is a LaTeX editor which has a special tab to insert delimiters and other practical things in your document.

[image: Tabs]

Answer (score 0):

This was stated above but I really like using the `physics` package, specifically the `\qty` command for auto-sized parentheses, braces, brackets, etc. the only issue is how that command adds spacing that can look quite bad when you pair `\qty` with any function. for example: `\sin \qty(x)`. An easy workaround to this unpleasant consequence of the `\qty` command is just adding a negative space from: `\!`. To make my example from above `\sin \! \qty(x)`, I find this to be easier than the `\left(\right)`since that also produces the same unwanted space that `\qty` makes. There are many more details on how to use the `physics` package here: http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/physics/physics.pdf. thanks for reading my response!