# Can the effect of \strut under a root sign be reduced?

Tags: math-mode

The effect of \strut on the vertical spacing under a square root is very severe.  I would like the effect to be about 20% of what it is.  Otherwise, strut solves a lot of problems.

```
% without \strut
\noindent \hspace{18pt}\large$\bigg[\hspace{1.4pt}x\hspace{1.4pt}'\hspace{-0.6pt}+\dfrac{\big(\hspace{0.4pt}9\hspace{-0.6pt}-\hspace{-0.6pt}5\hspace{0.4pt}\surd{\hspace{1.0pt}2}\hspace{0.8pt}\big) \hspace{1.2pt}\sqrt{  \hspace{1.2pt}4\hspace{-0.6pt}+\hspace{-0.6pt}2\hspace{0.4pt}\surd{\hspace{1.0pt}2}}}{62}\hspace{0.8pt}\bigg]^{\hspace{0.8pt}2}$

% with \strut
\vspace{6pt}
\noindent \hspace{18pt}$\bigg[\hspace{1.4pt}x\hspace{1.4pt}'\hspace{-0.6pt}+\dfrac{\big(\hspace{0.4pt}9\hspace{-0.6pt}-\hspace{-0.6pt}5\hspace{0.4pt}\surd{\hspace{1.0pt}2}\hspace{0.8pt}\big) \hspace{1.2pt}\sqrt{\strut\hspace{1.2pt}4\hspace{-0.6pt}+\hspace{-0.6pt}2\hspace{0.4pt}\surd{\hspace{1.0pt}2}}}{62}\hspace{0.8pt}\bigg]^{\hspace{0.8pt}2}$
```

Comment: try `\mathstrut` -- that's what it's for.  on the other hand, if the situation gets too complicated, the answer by @Ulrike explains what's happening.

Comment: This is very similar to the idea of `\delimitershortfall` where a minuscule adjustment in some formula contents could cause the `\left`-`\right` delimiters to stretch. As reference, see [Automatic size adjustment for nested parentheses](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36039/5764).

Answer (score 2):

You will have to try to use a bit smaller \strut. As you can see in the following example, a difference of 0.1pt can lead to quite a jump in the size:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
 $\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}$.

 $\sqrt{\rule{0pt}{\ht\strutbox}(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}$.

 $\sqrt{\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr \ht\strutbox+0.1pt}(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}$.

 $\sqrt{\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr \ht\strutbox+0.2pt}(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}$.

 $\sqrt{\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr \ht\strutbox+0.3pt}(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ulrike, Yes, the effect is very much non-linear.  The effect is hardly perceptible, then dramatically too much.

Comment: Barbara, I've tried \mathstrut, but is appears to do nothing. Whatever I try, appears to give a non-linear result: i.e. very little space, then a huge change.  It is as if there is an either/or in the code.

Comment: Barbara Beeton/ Ulrike Fischer I think this is a common problem for many writers with no satisfactory solution; could someone look into it, please.

Comment: There is not much anyone can do. It is the way the root is implemented: At some point it switches to the next symbol with a more vertical base. So it is never linear.

Comment: I agree, that's the way it currently is, but that's not to say it cannot be fixed so as to be perfectly progressive, is it?

Comment: perfectly progressive would be a bit much -- you can't put an infinity of glyphs in a font. But if you want more intermediary root symbols you will have to contact the various font designers. I would concentrate on the open type math fonts.