# Q: How to automatically size nested parenthesis?

Tags: math-mode, macros, math-operators

For instance, given this:

```
((a+b)c)^d
```

I'd like it to show:

```
\big((a+b)c\big)^d
```

but without the need to explicitly state `\big`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There are `\left(...\right)` etc. which you could nest, but it is not always advisable to use those.

Comment: @TeXnician Well, `$\left(\left(a+b\right)c\right)^d$` would not use larger parentheses for the outer ones; only unwanted spaces would be added.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried \left(\right), however, they only resize when the middle part gets larger. If it stays the same size, there's no size difference.

@egreg lol, yea my bad on that part

Comment: @japseow In general, there's no need to grow the outer parentheses large, so there's no automatic way to do it, because judgment is required. In any case, you should use `\bigl(` and `\bigr)`.

Comment: But, i have these predicates & quantifiers that requires a lot of ()
`pathConnected((M, \mathcal{O}), ()) \iff \forall_{p, q \in M} \exists_{\gamma} (continuous(\gamma, (([0, 1], \mathcal{O}_{standard}|_{[0 ,1]}), (M, \mathcal{O}))) \land \gamma(0) = p \land \gamma(1) = q) `
What should I do with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

I ended up just using a python script that searches for nested parenthesis and replaces it with `\left, \right`. I used `\pr` for parenthesis in my case.

`tex = re.sub(r"\(([^()\n]*?)\((.*?)\)([^()\n]*?)\)", r"\\pr{\1(\2)\3}", tex)`

Answer (score 9):

I suggest you load the `mleftright` package, issue the directive `\mleftright` (to avoid the unwanted insertion of extra whitespace), and issue the instruction `\delimitershortfall-1sp`. That way, the auto-sized parentheses will grow in size automatically, even if the enclosed material isn't "tall".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\delimitershortfall-1sp
\usepackage{mleftright}
\mleftright % make \left & \right behave like \mleft & \mright 
\begin{document}
\[
\left(\left\langle\left\{\left[\left(\left(a+b%
 \right)c\right)\right]\right\}\right\rangle\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

If you were to comment out the instruction `\delimitershortfall-1sp`, you'd get

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I want to add another solution, because a negative `\delimtershortfall` can look a bit unpleasant.

What I do is declaring a parenthis-function that uses `\vphantom` with `\raisebox` to add extra height to the outer delimiter.

The solution is not pretty:

- I use `\mathop` because else `\vphantom` does not work and then add negative space to counter the extra space that `\mathop` adds.
- Also inside `\raisebox` you need to use `\( \)` to get into mathmode and `\displaystyle` to get the right virtual height

But it works for me and you can still tweak `\delimtershortfall` and `\delimiterfactor` to your liking (if you then also adjust the raise in `\raisebox`).
Also you can change the value in `\raisebox` to adjust the growth of the delimiters.

For further reading I recommend this post:
[automatic size adjustment for nested parentheses](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36039/automatic-size-adjustment-for-nested-parentheses)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mleftright}


\global\delimitershortfall=5.5pt
\global\delimiterfactor=880
\renewcommand*{\left}{\mleft}
\renewcommand*{\right}{\mright}
\newcommand{\braced}[1]
    { \left( #1 \right) 
        \mskip-1.5mu \vphantom{ \mathop{
           \raisebox{3pt}{ \(\left(\displaystyle #1 \right)\) } } }
    }

\begin{document}
    \[
    \braced{ x + \braced{\braced{ y }} }
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image: Example]