# Bigger Parentheses And Brackets When Nested

Tags: brackets, parentheses

Is there any way to have parentheses and brackets that get bigger when "nested"?

For example, normally parentheses and brackets work like in the first case shown in the picture, but I would like to know if there is a way, preferably a package, to have something like the effect of the second case shown in the picture.

[image]

Comment: I'd say there is no reason to scale here. The first image is perfectly readable, perfectly clear what is fenced in and how. In the latter, the fences dominate the expression too much

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Q: How to automatically size nested parenthesis?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/391933/5764)

Comment: Also similar, assuming you want an automatic solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360996 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36039/ If you don't need an automatic solution, then there is `\bigl`/`\Bigl`/`\biggl`/`\Biggl` (for left brackets) and `\bigr` etc. for right brackets. E.g. `\biggl( .. \biggr)`.