# Sizes of nested parentheses in exponents

Tags: amsmath

I like the idea of "stacked sizes" in nested parentheses as discussed in [this Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36039/automatic-size-adjustment-for-nested-parentheses). However, the nath package seems not to work anymore - it doesn't texify.

So considering this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
   f(g(x)) \qquad \text{better:} \qquad f\bigl(g(x)\bigr) \\
   a^{f(g(x))} \qquad a^{f\bigl(g(x)\bigr)}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

yields "unnatural" big parentheses when used in exponent:

[image: yields "unnatural" big parentheses when used in exponent:]

Any suggestions / ideas?

Comment: Are you looking for feedback as to which of the size choices are better within exponents?

Comment: No - I'm looking for ideas how to fix this. In my opinion, the lower right expression looks terrible. So, I'm looking for a parenthesis size that is somewhere between () and \bigl(\bigr) when used in an exponent.

Comment: size commands like `\bigl` are simply not designed to change size in sub and superscripts, the intended markup here is to simply use `(`

Answer (score 1):

Making larger parentheses in superscript will probably not make things better, as `\textstyle` is the next larger size after `\scriptstyle`. However, you could reduce the size of the parentheses around the *x*.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{relsize}
\begin{document}
\[ \begin{aligned}
   f(g(x)) && \text{better:} && f\bigl(g(x)\bigr) \\
   a^{f(g(x))} && \text{better:} && a^{f(g\mathsmaller(x\mathsmaller))}
\end{aligned} \]
\end{document}
```

Here I used the `\mathsmaller` command from the `relsize` package, but if you don't want to use this package you can replace `\mathsmaller(` by `{\scriptscriptstyle(}` (and the same thing with `)`) to get the exact same output.