# Making *all* brackets scalable in a LaTeX document

Tags: math-mode, brackets

It is possible to have a pair of brackets adjust to their content by typing `\left` and `\right` before the respective brackets, whether they're round, square or curly, or even if they're special brackets like absolute value denoters, and so on.

**The question:** How to make virtually *all* brackets expand to the vertical size of their content automatically throughout an entire document, without having to type in `\left` and `\right` all the time? And how to occasionally escape this curse when I *don't* want this behaviour?

The reason I'm asking is because I use LaTeX for homework, which has proved out to work pretty good in terms of speed and effectiveness, as well as aesthetics. However, that expandable bracket thing is slowing me down quite a bit, and might eventually be the cause of me switching back to writing on good old paper.

Comment: Almost everyone agrees this is a bad idea, but there are ways to do it in the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

This a duplicate of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36039/automatic-size-adjustment-for-nested-parentheses). Try using the `nath` package with `\delimgrowth=1`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, nath}
\delimgrowth=1

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
[(\{1 + \frac{x}{y}\})]
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `$$..$$` is depreciated. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to

Comment: I've upvoted, because your code runs fine on its own. Unfortunately, I can't check this as the solution to my problem, because loading `nath` in any of my pre-existing documents results in *tons* of errors. Also have I noticed, by reading many other TeX.SE posts, that `nath` is a very stubborn and fragile package. Thank you for your clear and concise answer, though. I appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. Maybe try using `\qty` from the `physics` package.