# array within frac, using nath package

Tags: math-mode, arrays, fractions

I use the [nath](http://mirrors.ctan.org/help/Catalogue/entries/nath.html) package to get [automatically-sized delimiters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1753/5699), but it breaks having a `\begin{array}{…}…\end{array}` within a `\frac{}{}` (simply removing the `\usepackage{nath}` below fixes the example, but I need nath for other stuff).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{array}{c}a\\b\\c\end{array}% This works
  \frac{numerator}{denominator}% This works
  % I want to put the array at the numerator's place
  \frac{\begin{array}{c}a\\b\\c\end{array}}{denominator}% This fails
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I'm trying to do this to typeset some simple [natural deduction proofs](http://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/nd/) (one or several hypotheses followed by a horizontal line, then one or several conclusions), but packages like bussproofs.sty are clearly overkill (I don't need to typeset full proofs, just a single deduction rule). While `\frac{}{}` is semantically incorrect for this use, it is simple and gives the visual result I need.

**Edit**: The error message is `ERROR: LaTeX Error: Environment ARRAY undefined.`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For some reason, `nath` uses `\uppercase` when working on fractions (I've not checked the details, but the error message is about `ARRAY` being undefined).

This hack seems to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nath}
\newenvironment{ARRAY}[2][c]{\lowercase{\array[#1]{#2}}}{\endarray}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{array}{c}a\\b\\c\end{array}\quad
  \frac{numerator}{denominator}\quad
  \frac{\begin{array}{c}a\\b\\c\end{array}}{denominator}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

A less hackish way is to hide `array`:

```
\newcommand{\morelines}[1]{\begin{array}{c}#1\end{array}}
```

and

```
\begin{equation}
\frac{\morelines{a\\b\\c}}{denominator}
\end{equation}
```

or even

```
\newcommand{\morelines}[1]{\begin{array}{c}#1\end{array}}
\newcommand{\deduction}[2]{\frac{\morelines{#1}}{\morelines{#2}}}
```

and inputting your deduction as

```
\begin{equation}
\deduction{a\\b\\c}{denominator}
\end{equation}
```

---

<sub>I'm more convinced about not using `nath`.</sub>

Comment: @GeorgesDupéron I've added a less hackish method

Comment: A documentation with `$$...$$` gives the result -- I am too old.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel : What do you mean ? I don't get it. Besides, thanks for the update egreg :) .

Comment: @GeorgesDupéron: The documentation use `$$...$$` for there examples. However this isn't correct.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I don't know why `$$` is used in the documentation. I'm more concerned about using `nath` in general: it takes too much for granted. For instance, a formula like the one on page 4 (`A/B\otimes C/D`) would *rarely* be written with full fractions in display mode, in my field.

Answer (score 2):

After some more trial and error, I found that `\hline` works in the `array` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{array}{c}
    Hypothesis_1\\
    Hypothesis_2\\
    \hline
    Conclusion_1
  \end{array}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

This gives the visual result I want, and doesn't have `\frac{}{}`'s semantic mismatch, however the arrays have a different vertical alignment, and tend to collide with what's left and right of them (they need a little more horizontal padding), so [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60180/5699) is better.

Answer (score 2):

For the particular example in the question, a `\matrix` could be used as well

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \frac{\matrix a\\ b\\ c\strut\endmatrix}{`denominator}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]