# How do I type large set brackets that look like this

Tags: symbols

How can I get the set brackets to look like this?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! See if [How to make brackets larger?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83286) answers your question.

Comment: See also [bigger parentheses in equations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78736)

Comment: "to look like this?" instead of like what? Please clarify, e.g. by showing us what you've come up with so far. Right now it seems like you're asking about some of the most basic tools found in every tutorial.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\left\{` and `\right\}`. They autosize your brackets around your content and the item that follows them, in this case `\{`, is the delimiter.

Comment: Note that `\left{` is illegal.

Answer (score 3):

With `mathtools` you can define a `\set` command, which accepts an optional argument: `\big, \Big,&c.` to control the size of the brackets. The starred version is equivalent of a pair of `\left ··· \right` around the braces.

As to the separator, @egreg pointed there's a small difference between `:` and `\colon`. I propose both, so the choice depends on one's taste:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\set{\{}{\}}
\newcommand\numberset[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand\Real{\numberset{R}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*} 
& \set*{\begin{pmatrix}x + 2y\\x\\-y\end{pmatrix}: x, y\in\Real} \\[3ex]
&\set*{\begin{pmatrix}x + 2y\\x\\-y\end{pmatrix}\colon x, y\in\Real}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Should `\colon` be used instead of `:`?

Comment: You're right. Not sure may people will see the difference (~0.6pt more horizontal spacing after the colon), nor that's worth the typing (unless we get it it automatically in the place of `:` using `xparse`. At any rate I changed it. Thanks for your eagle-eye ;o)

Comment: @Mico No; here the colon is used as a relation symbol, so `:` is the right input; `\colon` leaves a small space at its left and a larger space at its right.

Comment: @egreg: I noticed that, and that's why I ultimately preferred it…

Comment: I hope you don't mind my edit, then. I recommend `\mathbf{R}` instead of `\mathbf R`: the former requires two keystrokes more, but it's clearer. Of course one should have `\newcommand{\numberset}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}` and then `\newcommand\real{\numberset{R}}`, so as to get uniform appearance without needing explicit mark up.

Comment: I don't mind at all. I'll just add the other version, so the readers may choose knowingly.Your suggestion for a `\numberset` command is excellent, and I'll retain it!

Comment: @egreg - Thanks for clearing up my mis-understanding of the role/purpose of the `:` symbol in this example.