# How to avoid this undesired horizontal space?

Tags: align

In the following output, why do I get the undesired space before the `(`, and how to get rid of it globally?
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
&a=b\\
&\left(a\right)=b
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There's no need to use `\left` and `\right` there; it's a good example of why they should be used only when necessary. Can you give a more realistic example?

Comment: @egreg this is just an example to show the space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `align` enviroment always starts the second column (and all even numbered ones) with an empty object, because usually one starts these columns with a relation symbol and the empty object guarantees correct spacing.

The math mode spacing rules, however, tell that between an ordinary symbol (the empty object, in this case) and an Inner atom (the subformula delimited by `\left` and `\right`) a thin space is inserted.

This is a good example showing why `\left` and `\right` should *not* be used in general, but only when they really serve a purpose.

There is a workaround, anyway:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mleftright}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
&a=b\\
&\mleft(a\mright)=b
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is however *not* a good reason to use indiscriminately `\mleft` and `\mright`. For instance,

```
\[
\mleft(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i\mright)
\]
```

is significantly worse than

```
\[
\biggl(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i\biggr)
\]
```

[image]

Comment: @egreg thanks, but in your MWE, there is still a thin space before the `(`! One more thing: Why is `\mleft` worse than `\biggl`?

Comment: @egreg.  I'm curious, you say your example with `\mleft` is *significantly worse* than that with `\biggl`.  That's the opposite conclusion I was expecting from you (though I do agree with about not indiscriminately using `\mleft`).  Do you care to explain why you feel your `\mleft` example is worse in your eyes?

Comment: @VahidDamanafshan and A.Ellet I don't know if this is what he means, but in my case is worse because it doesn't look good (it's too bigger, in that case, and the correct size, to my eyes, is the second one, which has to be written manually).

Comment: @VahidDamanafshan The tiny space is due to the shape of the parenthesis; just try without `\mleft` and `\mright` and you'll have the very same result. You can say `\mleftright` in the preamble; then `\left` will mean `\mleft` and `\right` will be `\mright`.

Comment: @A.Ellett I think that just looking at the two typeset formulas shows that the `\biggl`-`\biggr` version is better than the `\left`-`\right` one, which has too tall delimiters.