# A taller version of \parallel

Tags: symbols

I need a taller version of `\parallel` in order to typeset a norm correctly. I have tried variations of things like

```
\Bigg{\parallel}
```

and

```
\left{\parallel} \right{\parallel}
```

but receive the error "Missing delimiter (. inserted)" with the file not compiling. Any suggestions would be appreciated...

Comment: this is a variant of the question [Automatic left and right commands](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1742/579).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\parallel` isn't defined as a delimiter which is necessary to work with `\left` and `\right`. To achieve the desired effect try:

```
\[\left\lVert \frac a b\right\rVert\]
```

This needs `amsmath`, so make sure you load it.

Comment: `\rVert` would be better on the right side.

Answer (score 8):

if you're using the norm notation frequently, you might want to define a
command `\norm` using the `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` feature of `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}

\begin{document}
\[
\norm{a} + \norm[\bigg]{\frac{1}{a}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

this "helper" command provides the ability to specify a size option as shown,
and a starred version automatically applies `\left` and `\right`.
`mathtools` automatically loads `amsmath`, loading that separately isn't necessary.

a more complete explanation of how to automatically provide `\left` and `\right` commands for paired delimiters is given by [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1742/579), and the present answer is a variant on the [answer to that question by lev bishop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1765/579).

Answer (score 5):

The simpliest way:

```
\[
\left\| x \right\|
\]
```