# Missing delimiter (. inserted) when using pmatrix

Tags: delimiters

I am trying to compile this and I get the 'Missing delimiter (. inserted)' error even though overleaf manages to display what I want

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\vect}[3]{
    \left
    \begin{pmatrix} 
        #1\\[0.3 em]
        #2\\[0.3 em] 
        #3 
    \end{pmatrix}  
    \right.
}

\begin{document}
\[
\vect{1}{2}{3}
\]
\end{document}
```

could you help me? (sorry if my question is stupid, I am a beginner)

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/279200/107497 clarify what's going wrong?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  The reason for the error message is the presence of the `\left` before the `pmatrix`.  `\left` requires an explicit "fence".  Since `pmatrix` automatially provides the fences, `\left` and `\roight` aren't needed.

Comment: You need `\left(`, `\left[`, `\left\{`, etc. but not `\left`. However, as Barbara Beeton said, `\left...` and `\right.` here are not necessary

Comment: It works by writting \left( and \right). and replacing pmatrix by matrix but not by just removing \left and \right. is that normal?

Comment: You will get better spacing from `pmatrix` than from `\left(\begin{matrix}`