# Tips, commands, advice that made your TeXing easier, faster or prettier

Tags: learning, workflow

*Sometimes* StackExchange sites permit on-topic, soft question, community wiki answers, if they're constructive and interesting enough to the community.  I hope this fits.

I'm wondering moments in your TeXing career you learned something

- that saved you a lot of time
- improved your workflow
- led to production of nicer documents

I will post my example that inspired this question and hope to learn useful facts.

Comment: Always ask yourself, is this package a tool or a prison?

Answer (score 2):

For the categories

> - that saved you a lot of time
> - improved your workflow

my answer is automation tools! These save me a lot of time and thinking as they automatically compile the needed number of tex runs and the bibliography.

- for quick documents, like for answering questions on this site, my tool of choice is `latexmk`
- for more complex projects I found [ltx2any](https://github.com/akerbos/ltx2any) very comfortable to use
- and ultimately for a maximum of possibilities and control I love to use [arara](https://github.com/cereda/arara)

For a more exhaustive list of available tools, see [Tools for automating document compilation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64/tools-for-automating-document-compilation)

Answer (score 0):

On math.SE many people are missing good uses of `\left` and `\right`.

```
(\frac45)
```

v.

```
\left(\frac45\right)
```

More detail here: ["(" or "\left(" parentheses?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12773/or-left-parentheses) (IMO just using \left and \right in simple situations is often an improvement).

Following through to [link in comment](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nath): The package nath seeks to obsolete this. Even better (but I've never used it so cannot offer an example at this time).

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1742/automatic-left-and-right-commands for why `\left` and `\right` should be used selectively

Comment: @JosephWright seems nath obsoletes it. good to learn.

Comment: Also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12773/or-left-parentheses