# How do I get a more compact version of `\left(`, `\right)` and friends?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, parentheses

In math mode, specifying auto-scaled parentheses/brackets/braces stands in the way due to the long commands, degrading readability.
Is there an alternative which can be read easier?

Is there any catch to defining `(` to be `\left(` in math mode?
How would I do that (for math mode only)?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1742/automatic-left-and-right-commands and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12773/or-left-parentheses for some problems with this

Comment: the spacing of `\left(..` is usually suboptimal, you certainly would not want to write `(x+y)` as `\left(x+y\right)`

Comment: @david-carlisle: I've noticed that when using `\left(f\right)` with certain fonts, where the `f` is rendered italic, which looks pretty ugly. Now I know this is a common issue. Thanks!

Comment: even with the default computer modern using left right adds additional horizontal space, even in the case that the delimiters are not made larger,