# Absolute Value Symbols in LyX

Tags: lyx

I've been looking for a way to use the `\abs` command in LyX (Version 2.3.0, using MikTex) but unfortunately I didn't find a solution.

For a reason I'm not aware of, this command does not appear as an option in a math box. I tried defining it as a macro:

[image]

with `\lvert` and `\rvert`, which is ok except for the fact that it doesn't scale. I read that there is something called a "starred" version of a command, which should solve the scaling problem ,but I didn't manage to define the macro as such.

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: The standard LaTeX way would be to use `\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}` using the macro from `mathtools` as described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1742/15925.  Usable as `\abs[\big]{X^Y}` and `\abs*{\frac{A}{X^2+Y^2}}`.

Comment: I've tried putting this line _\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}_ in Document->Settings...->LaTeX Preamble, but I didn't notice any change. The \abs command is still not available.
Is this the right place where it should be added?

Comment: I don't think adding a latex command to the preamble makes LyX generate an interface for it. You'll need to input it as direct latex code in order to use it

Comment: Are any errors reported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the package AND declaration in your preamble

Insert your TeX compile and enjoy!

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it works :)
Please allow me to bother you with another question: do you know how I can add LaTeX code as a macro in LyX?

Comment: That is not an area I am familiar with and best raised as a fresh question

Answer (score 0):

***Simply*** click on "[blue box]" (the blue box is actual blue box) at the bottom, i.e., last one in the series () [] {} **[blue box]**. It is the "insert delimiters" option. A pop up as "math delimiter" will appear. Use it (for absolute sign | & |). It will resize automatically.