# Making command to add \left and \right to brackets that are within an equation block (within $$)

Tags: brackets, renewcommand

Just wondering if there is a way to replace the brackets - '(' and ')' within equations with '\left(' and '\right)' but not replace the brackets within general text.

For example, in the body of a latex document

```
This is normal text (these brackets should not be replaced).
On the other hand, this equation - $(\dfrac{x}{2})$ should have it's brackets replaced, such that it outputs $\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)$
```

I'm assuming I would have to use the `\renewcommand` to handle the bracket replacement. But not sure how (and if it's possible) to do this bracket replacement conditionally (to only occur within equations)

Comment: Welcome to TeX StackExchange! Because parentheses are characters and not commands, you can't really use `\renewcommand` to redefine them. Would any of these solutions be an acceptable alternative for your needs? [Automatic left and right commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1742/automatic-left-and-right-commands)

Comment: There’s no reason whatsoever for using `\left` and `\right` next to each use of parentheses or brackets. Rather, there are good reasons for not doing it.

Comment: The reason for using the `\left` and `\right` is to help enlarge the brackets so that they don't look awkwardly small, when housing a `\dfrac{}{}`

Comment: I'm just trying to find a quick solution (that doesn't require other functions such as `br{}`) as I have quite a few documents that I need this implemented for, that already have brackets in place! - and don't have time to change them all